# Left join that is not showing all left table values

Tags: sql, join, left-join

A LEFT JOIN should show all rows on the left table however when running the following query, I am only getting place values where there is a count of 1 or more. Please can someone give me some guidance as to where I might be going wrong:

```
SELECT places.placeId,
       placeName,
       COUNT(orderId) AS orderCount
FROM   places
       LEFT JOIN orders
         ON places.placeId = orders.placeId
WHERE  places.companyId = 1
       AND stateId = 1
       AND orderstateId = 1
       AND orderName NOT LIKE 'Delivery%'
GROUP  BY places.placeId,
          places.placeName
ORDER  BY orderCount DESC,
          placeName ASC
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What table are all the various columns in your query from? If any of `stateId,orderstateId,orderName` are in `orders` you need to move the relevant filter into the join rather than the `where`.

Comment: @MartinSmith Put that in an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: stateId, orderstateId and orderName are all from the orders table. I can get round it by doing a second query that gets all places which have no orders but I was trying to avoid that if possible

Comment: @Barmar - Done. Was waiting for the OP to confirm the columns rather than supplying an answer based on possibly wrong assumptions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition converts the `OUTER JOIN` back to an `INNER JOIN`.

The non matched rows will have `NULL` for all the `orders` columns and be eliminated by the `WHERE` clause. Try this.

```
SELECT places.placeId,
       placeName,
       COUNT(orderId) AS orderCount
FROM   places
       LEFT JOIN orders
         ON places.placeId = orders.placeId
       AND orders.stateId = 1
       AND orders.orderstateId = 1
       AND orders.orderName NOT LIKE 'Delivery%'
WHERE  places.companyId = 1
GROUP  BY places.placeId,
          places.placeName
ORDER  BY orderCount DESC,
          placeName ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If these columns `stateID`, `orderstateID`, and `OrderName` came from `ORDERS` table then you will have a problem then. As you can see, If `places.placeID` is not present on `orders` table, the following columns are `nulls` for the `orders` table. And that's the reason why some records won't show because of the condition you have provided on `orders` table.

Answer (score 1):

Even when you use a `LEFT JOIN`, all rows have to meet the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.  In this case, the `WHERE` clause has requirements related to `orders`, thus you won't return any rows where `orders` doesn't match to `places`.

A simple fix would be to allow null values to satisfy your `WHERE` clause:

`orderstateId = 1`

changes to

`(orderstateId is NULL or orderstateId = 1)`

And likewise for the other variables.

This would probably do what you want, but you have to check if rows with null values in the `orders` table could then be included and mess up your result.  It might be better to redesign your query in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying `orderstateId = 1`. I guess this binds to `orders.orderstateId = 1`. This conditions fails for a null `orderstateId` which happens when left-joining without match.

Change it to `orders.orderstateId = 1 OR orders.orderstateId IS NULL`