# Mysql Left Join does not return all values

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a simple mysql query that work fine but it does not return all the values . All the values are returned when I use the left joined table alone but when I add the other tables only those that are all "=" return a value. Here is the query:

```
SELECT 

d.flight_no   , b.arrival_flight

FROM  
jtl_booking_transfer_details                    AS      b
LEFT  JOIN jtl_flight_info                      AS      d      
       ON  (d.flight_no      b.arrival_flight),

jtl_booking_master                                     a,
jtl_hotels                                             c,                                                               
jtl_airlines                                           e


WHERE 

a.voucher_number                             =        b.voucher_number             AND 
b.hotel_id                                   =        c.hotel_id                   AND
e.airline_code                               =        d.airline_code
```

Comment: What do you mean by `only those that are all "=" return a value`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Left join that is not showing all left table values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675162/left-join-that-is-not-showing-all-left-table-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same syntax for getting all tables (easier to read : JOIN for ... joining tables, WHERE clause for other predicates)

```
SELECT 
d.flight_no   , b.arrival_flight

FROM  
jtl_booking_transfer_details b
LEFT JOIN jtl_flight_info d      
   ON  d.flight_no = b.arrival_flight
LEFT JOIN  jtl_booking_master a 
   ON a.voucher_number = b.voucher_number
LEFT JOIN jtl_hotels c 
   ON b.hotel_id = c.hotel_id
LEFT JOIN jtl_airlines  e 
   ON  e.airline_code = d.airline_code
```

Comment: The query above does work now but when I add WHERE d.flight_no = ifnull(%s,d.flight_no) it only return values where flight numbers are equal.

Comment: My boss helped me with this query here is the solution for the where clause:                                                   IFNULL(d.flight_no ,'XX') = IFNULL(%s,IFNULL(d.flight_no,'XX'))