# SQL - JOIN BETWEEN vs WHERE BETWEEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause, between

A few weeks ago I did a query (can't remember what for) and it involved the `BETWEEN` operator. At first, I used this in the `WHERE` clause, but it didn't produce the correct result set (again, I don't remember what the problem was). I thought about why and eventually concluded that I had to move it to the `JOIN` clause.

e.g.

"Original" query:

```
SELECT --something
FROM table1 a
/*type of*/ JOIN table2 b ON a.field = b.field
WHERE b.field2 BETWEEN a.field2 AND a.field3 /*some other conditions*/
```

Revised query:

```
SELECT --something
FROM table1 a
/*type of*/ JOIN table2 b ON a.field = b.field 
                       AND b.field2 BETWEEN a.field2 AND a.field3
WHERE /*some other conditions*/
```

The `JOIN` version returned a smaller result set compared to the `WHERE` version, and the `JOIN` version produced the correct result set whereas `WHERE` one didn't.

The reason I'm asking now is because at the time I thought nothing of it, but today my boss questioned why I did it (for an entirely different query) and I told him the experience I had the last time I did, and both he and I are quite intrigued as to the differences between the two usages.

From what I think as to why one produced something different to the other is that the `WHERE` clause version only *selected* a range of data, whereas the `JOIN` version looked for a range of data to *join* on. Is this the case? Or I did come across a unique experience affected by the rest of the query (the query was much more complicated than the examples).

**EDIT**
I disagree with the possible duplicate because my one looks specifically at the `BETWEEN` clause, not joins in general. I have read the mentioned post before and it didn't answer my question, hence why I posted this.

Comment: if you believe the error is caused by the syntax, please look at the data returned from both queries and create a simplified subset of that data that you can run these dummy queries against. if both queries return the correct results, the error is outside of this syntax. otherwise, post the sample data so we can recreate and diagnose.

Comment: WHERE/ON differ for OUTER JOINs. But you have only INNER one. So it doesn't matter which clauses are under ON and which are under WHERE. Your problem must be due to another condition.

Comment: @RoyalSwish Buddy; Nothing wrong from your side. No need to say sorry. `where clause and on clause are different for outer joins but linguistically behave as same for inner join.` and your post is different from that post. I just meant your post is just not a duplicate of 'that' post

Comment: @RoyalSwish But Buddy; If you would have used `outer joins` in you original queries and as you say: `the post was to cover all types of joins, I just picked INNER JOIN as an example, that's why the title just says 'join'` Then it surely matters. The above queries may bring different results for outer joins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72847/discussion-between-avidan-and-royalswish).

Comment: possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between two versions, except if you have wrong precedence in one of them due to lack of parentheses.

Comment: As long as it's inner joins and not outer joins!

Comment: @jarlh Yes. Both versions above use only INNER JOIN. If they had OUTER one, that would be totally different.