# LEFT JOIN query not returning all rows in first table

Tags: sql, left-join

Using management studio for `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

Trying to do a `LEFT JOIN` and I need to return all rows from the first table regardless of the row being able to tie with the second table.
Not sure I explained that right.

This is what I got right now:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.store, b.stock
from products a left join stock b
on a.id = b.id
where b.store = '001'
order by a.id
```

I need the query to return all products that the company sells and also show it's stock in store `001`.

But the way it is right now it will only show the rows that have mention of the product stock in store `001`.

So, basically, I need the query to return `0` stock if the `001` store is not mentioned.

All products that only have stock in store `002` need to be listed as well, with a `0` as it's stock.

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. An inner join on or where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join". You have that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. [ask]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Move the b condition from `WHERE` to `ON` to get a real `LEFT JOIN`. (With the b condition in the `WHERE` clause, it executes as a regular `inner join`...)

```
select a.id, a.name, b.store, b.stock
from products a left join stock b
  on a.id = b.id and b.store = '001'
order by a.id
```

Comment: Boom! Thank you, will accept as soon as the system allows it

Comment: You will also want to `coalesce(b.stock, 0)` to ensure that you get `0` for stock after execution.

Comment: I added that myself but used `isnull` instead. Thank you