# MySQL: Select query with many AND/OR conditions

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, where-clause

I have a very large dataset, and I am trying to do a LEFT outer join, but keep losing some of my left table rows because of where I place my WHERE command, similar to the problem and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592768/left-join-query-not-returning-all-rows-in-first-table).

**Example 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
    USING (IDvar)
    WHERE table2.var IN(val1, val2,..., val100);
```

This only selects the rows in the first/left table (table1) that have a matching row in the second/right table (table2). The second example is what is likely to work:

**Example 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
    USING (IDvar)
    AND (table2.var = val1 OR table2.var = val2);
```

But, I have like 200 `table2.var` values that I would like to include, which are sporadic and and non-continuous (can't use syntax like `table2.var >= val1`).

An example of what I thought should work is to use "AND" and "IN" such as (because I have the values as a comma-separated list):

**Example 3**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 
    USING (IDvar)
    AND table2.var IN(val1, val2,..., val100);
```

So how can I get many many values into an AND command?

I've found a working solution, but it takes way way to long to perform.

**Example 4 - Working Example but takes too long**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT table2.var WHERE table2.var IN(val1, val2,..., val100)) AS t
    USING (IDvar);
```

Is there any way of optimising this query, it is taking way too long?

Comment: you can do an "Inner join" with  Services table  instead of   "in" condition

Comment: Check my edit. An inner join would mean I would lose many of the table1 rows that don't have a matching row in table 2, which is the problem I have been having using the where command.

Comment: Use the third example, replacing IN with FIND_IN_SET

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but switching out the IN with FIND_IN_SET throws an error, and even when I modify it like in the MySQL docs. It seems to really need the WHERE clause, but that subsets my Left table (table1) and I need to have all my records in table 1, regardless if they match. I'm pretty sure I found a working solution using a subquery, but the subquery takes forever to run.