# MYSQL ALL rows from first table and join columns from other table with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables and I want all the rows of the first table, the union with the second table will depend on 2 things, the first, that the `ID_NAMES` match and the second, that the column `OPENED` is zero , otherwise fill with null. Example

First table `names`

```
ID_NAMES   NAME
   1       test1
   2       test2
   3       test3
   4       test4
```

Second Table `surprise`

```
ID_SURPRICE  ID_NAMES   ELEMENT   OPENED
     1           3        lion        0
     2           2         dog        1
     3           1         cat        0
```

I want the next result

```
ID_NAMES NAMES ID_SURPRICE  ID_NAMES   ELEMENT   OPENED
     1   test1      3          1         cat        0
     2   test2     null       null       null      null
     3   test3      1          3         lion       0
     4   test4     null       null       null      null
```

I perform the query in the following way but it only returns the ones that coincide with the `where`

```
SELECT names.*, surprise.* 
FROM names
    LEFT JOIN surprise
        ON names.ID_NAMES = surprise.ID_NAMES 
where surprise.OPENED = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want the answer here:

[LEFT JOIN query not returning all rows in first table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592768/left-join-query-not-returning-all-rows-in-first-table/30592831)

Basically, if I add a where I am doing an `inner join`, so I have to move the clause to the `on`

```
SELECT names.*, surprise.* 
FROM names
    LEFT JOIN surprise
        ON names.ID_NAMES = surprise.ID_NAMES AND surprise.OPENED = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Although you used left join but the overall query is acting like inner join that's why you didn't get your expected result.**

- See the changes

```sql
SELECT names.*, surprise.* 
FROM names
    LEFT JOIN surprise
        ON names.ID_NAMES = surprise.ID_NAMES and surprise.OPENED = 0
;
```

**Tips: When you use left, right join then you need to be careful at this scenario. Using condition in where clause the query will perform like `inner join`**