# Return default result for IN value regardless

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that gets all user that have been online between a certain date range. This is done via an IN query due to how I want to display the data. However, I would like to return a default value if no records were found for an ID that was parsed into the IN condition.

Simplified Query:

```
SELECT users.Name, users.ID, SUM(users.Minutes) AS MinutesOnline
FROM UserTable
     LEFT JOIN OnlineUseage ON OnlineUseage.ID = UserTable.ID
WHERE OnlineUseage.Date >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND OnlineUseage.Date <= '2016-12-31 23:59:59'
AND UserTable.ID IN(332,554,5764,11,556,.........)
GROUP BY users.ID
ORDER BY FIELD(UserTable.ID, 332,554,5764,11,556,.........)
```

Now the above query will only pull in those row that meet the condition, as expected. I would also like the query to pull in a default value for the ID's within the IN condition that don't meet the condition.

Using `IFNULL` in this instance will not work as the record is never returned

```
SELECT users.Name, users.ID, IFNULL(SUM(users.Minutes), 0) AS MinutesOnline
FROM UserTable
    LEFT JOIN OnlineUseage ON OnlineUseage.ID = UserTable.ID
WHERE OnlineUseage.Date >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND OnlineUseage.Date <= '2016-12-31 23:59:59'
AND UserTable.ID IN(332,554,5764,11,556,.........)
GROUP BY users.ID
ORDER BY FIELD(UserTable.ID, 332,554,5764,11,556,.........)
```

FYI - i'm parsing this query into a custom PDO function. I'm not using deprecated mysql functions

Comment: Should `users.minutes` be `OnlineUseage.minutes`?

Comment: the value in IN clause are obtained from a subselect ?

Comment: There is no users table here. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a condition on `OnlineUseage` the left join become like a inner join.

move your condition to the `from` clause will be better :

```
SELECT
    users.Name,
    users.ID,
    IFNULL(SUM(users.Minutes), 0) AS MinutesOnline
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN OnlineUseage ON
        OnlineUseage.ID = users.ID and
        OnlineUseage.Date >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND
        OnlineUseage.Date <= '2016-12-31 23:59:59'
WHERE
    users.ID IN (332,554,5764,11,556,.........)
GROUP BY
    users.ID,users.Name
ORDER BY
    users.ID
```

Comment: Awesome! Can't believe I didn't think about moving the condition into the JOIN part. Thanks. Will mark as correct when allowed.

Comment: conditions on `OnlineUseage.Date` are applied before the join if they are on from clause

Comment: if you want select users.Name you need add it on group by (it's better). With another database it's mandatory.

Comment: @Indent My question has been marked duplicate against this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849705/unable-to-get-desired-output-using-mysql-joins-table-schema-and-test-data-prov/. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `LEFT JOIN` you have to put the conditions on the second table into the `ON` clause. Putting them in the `WHERE` clause filters out all the rows that don't have matches, because those columns will be `NULL` and the conditions will never succeed.

```
SELECT users.Name, users.ID, IFNULL(SUM(OnlineUseage.Minutes), 0) AS MinutesOnline
FROM UserTable
LEFT JOIN OnlineUseage ON OnlineUseage.ID = UserTable.ID
    AND OnlineUseage.Date >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND OnlineUseage.Date <= '2016-12-31 23:59:59'
WHERE UserTable.ID IN(332,554,5764,11,556,.........)
GROUP BY UserTable.ID
ORDER BY FIELD(UserTable.ID, 332,554,5764,11,556,.........)
```