# Querying tables with a zero-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many

I have an application that uses a MySQL database to store, asking other things, meetings and projects. A project can have zero-to-many meetings, and a meeting can have zero-to-many projects. To assist with linking meetings to a project, I'm trying to write a single clean query that searches across all of these tables and their relations (e.g. projects have tasks, meetings have attendees)

Here's an idea of the design:

project
- id
- reference
- description
- type

project_meetings
- id
- project_id
- meeting_id
- created_at
- created_by

meeting
- id
- reference

meeting_attendee
- id
- meeting_id
- person_id

person
- id
- name

project_tasks
- id
- project_id
- task_type_id
- content

task_types
- id
- task_title

The simplest idea I had was using LEFT JOINs, but I found it removes the results from the tables with zero related objects. The two ways that work are to use UNIONs, subqueries, or a really horrible WHERE-AND-OR clause with brackets for Africa.

Can anyone suggest a better query pattern for this design, or a better design?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` should include the results with no related objects. That's the difference between `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`. You must not be doing it correctly. Since you haven't posted your query, it's impossible to tell what you did wrong.

Comment: But I'll bet this answers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449631/return-default-result-for-in-value-regardless/47449788#47449788

Comment: You may want to look into FULL JOIN since you seem to want both the projects with no meetings and the meetings with no projects.

Comment: More details - it's mysql so no full joins possible, and i will post the query tomorrow...

Comment: Working on it... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0ce16

Answer (score 0):

> A project can have zero-to-many meetings

-->

```
CREATE TABLE Projects (
    id ...

CREATE TABLE Meetings (
    id ...
    project_id ... -- this is all you need for 0:many (or 1:many)
```

Your sqlfiddle show a "many-to-many" relationship between Products and Meetings, not "zero-to-many".  As such, it is inefficient.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

When `JOINing` the two tables, you *may* need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

> a single clean query that searches across all of these tables

Give an example of the output desired.