# Keep the row even when there is no value found SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to keep a row even when it is missing a value. But I just can't figure it out.

10.4.14-MariaDB

**The example query:**

```
SELECT
    data.name,
    am.value AS color
FROM
    color_data cd

    INNER JOIN color_data am
     ON cd.value = am.id

    INNER JOIN data
     ON cd.id = data.id

WHERE
    data.type = "vehicles"
    AND data.slug LIKE "%something%"
    AND cd.key = "color_id"
    AND am.key = "color"
```

**What I get:**

```
----------------------
   name   |  color   |
----------------------
 car      | red
 bicycle  | blue
```

**What I want:**

```
----------------------
   name   |  color   |
----------------------
 car      | red
 boat     |         <-- When this is empty keep the row.
 bicycle  | blue
```

SO when a color's ID is missing the row gets removed. I want to still keep that row. It's probably something fairly basic I'm missing.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449631/return-default-result-for-in-value-regardless/47449788#47449788 for how to put conditions on the `color` table when joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite your query with the JOINs starting from `data`, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, and put the conditions on the `color` tables in the join conditions:

```sql
SELECT
    data.name,
    am.value AS color
FROM
    data
LEFT JOIN
    color_data cd ON cd.id = data.id AND cd.key = 'color_id'
LEFT JOIN
    color_data am ON am.id = cd.value AND am.key = 'color'
WHERE
    data.type = 'vehicles'
AND data.slug LIKE '%something%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`s starting with the table where you want to keep all the rows:

```
SELECT data.name, am.value AS color
FROM data
     color_data cd LEFT JOIN
     ON cd.id = data.id AND
        cd.key = 'color_id' LEFT JOIN
     color_data am
     ON cd.value = am.id AND
        am.key = 'color'
WHERE data.type = 'vehicles' AND
      data.slug LIKE '%something%';
```

Notes:

- `data` is now first in the `FROM` clause because you want to keep those rows.
- Filtering conditions on `data` are in the `WHERE` clause.
- Filtering conditions on the other tables are in the appropriate `ON` clause.
- Single quotes are the SQL standard for strings, not double quotes.