# Correct mySQL query for Student attendance entry

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to develop a student attendance form using Codeigniter & MySQL. My table structure for the two tables are as follows:

```
student_mst table
-----------------
s_id(pk)
s_name
s_acssn_id 
s_prog_id
s_admission_no 
s_photo_name 

stu_attendance table
--------------------
sa_id(pk)
sa_s_id(fk)
sa_s_acssn_id
sa_s_prog_id
sa_atten_dt
sa_atten_code(A=Absent,P=Present)
sa_teacher_id
```

The design of my interface is as shown in the image below:
[image]

My plan is, on any particular date, a teacher can mark a student as either Present or Absent from the Action buttons for which ajax code is there which inserts rows in the above-mentioned stu_attendance table. **And also every new day when the attendance entry form is opened, the Datatable plugin should open just like as shown in the image.**

In order to accomplish my plans, I'm populating a Datatable plugin using the following query:

```
SELECT a.s_id AS sid,a.s_prog_id AS progid,a.s_acssn_id AS ssnid,a.s_name AS sname,a.s_admission_no AS sadmsnno,a.s_photo_name AS sphotonm,
       b.sa_atten_code AS acode 
FROM student_mst a 
LEFT JOIN stu_attendance b 
ON a.s_id = b.sa_s_id
```

The above SQL query works well for the first time (i.e. when stu_attendance table is empty)
and populates the Datatable plugin as shown in the above image. I'm able to mark students as Present/Absent.

However, my plan fails the next day, because as per the query written above, it also picks and shows records of the students from the previous day which is not desired.

I hope I have made my problems clear. Anyone, please guide me. Should I change my table structures or should I change my design interface or should change my SQL query. Please help maybe with some code/examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a date check to the join so it only shows the current day's attendance.

```
SELECT a.s_id AS sid,a.s_prog_id AS progid,a.s_acssn_id AS ssnid,a.s_name AS sname,a.s_admission_no AS sadmsnno,a.s_photo_name AS sphotonm,
       b.sa_atten_code AS acode 
FROM student_mst a 
LEFT JOIN stu_attendance b 
ON a.s_id = b.sa_s_id AND b.sa_atten_dt = CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply@Barmar. I did use the CURRENT_DATE() in my query, but that would return 0 records when the attendance table is empty and would not show my datatable plugin as shown in the image.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` should make it show all the students, even if they don't have an attendance record on that day.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar, previously I was writing like WHER b.sa_atten_dt = CURRENT_DATE() and it was returning 0 records.But following your suggestion to use AND b.sa_atten_dt = CURRENT_DATE() and its working perfectly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449631/return-default-result-for-in-value-regardless/47449788#47449788 for why the condition has to be in the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

use a where condition at the end of your query.
for example:

```
where date like '%19%August%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following query, it should work

```
SELECT a.s_id AS sid,a.s_prog_id AS progid,a.s_acssn_id AS ssnid,a.s_name AS 
   sname,a.s_admission_no AS sadmsnno,a.s_photo_name AS sphotonm,
       b.sa_atten_code AS acode 
  FROM student_mst a 
  LEFT JOIN stu_attendance b 
  ON a.s_id = b.sa_s_id AND b.sa_atten_dt >= date_format(curdate(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```