# Get all values from one table and check if they exists in other table, and brings data and NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all values from one table and check if they exists in other table, and brings data and NULL values.

These are my tables and I use Mysql
1-table **CS**

```
| id_m  | id_cs  |
|:-----:|:------:|
| 1     | 12     |
| 2     | 12     |
| 3     | 12     |
| 4     | 77     |
```

2-table **HC**

```
| id_m | id_cs |  idu  |
|:----:|:-----:|:-----:|
| 1    | 12    |   9   |
| 2    | 12    |   9   |
| 2    | 12    |   88  |
```

And the result I'm looking for is:

Bring me all CS.id_m from CS that **exists** and **NOT exists** in HC where HC.id_cs=12 and HC.idu=9

I need this:

```
| id_m | id_cs |  idu  |
|:----:|:-----:|:-----:|
| 1    | 12    |   9   |
| 2    | 12    |   9   |
| 3    | 12    |   NULL|
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Read about left join’s

Comment: Yes I tried but with no luck, when I add the "when" clause, it brings me only the exiting values without NULLS

Comment: Show us your LEFT JOIN attempt.

Comment: Conditions on the second table should be in the ON clause, not WHERE. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449631/return-default-result-for-in-value-regardless/47449788#47449788

Comment: Thank you All, I added all conditions in the ON statement instead of WHERE, now it works