# SQL Query for getting First Instance IF Between Two Dates

Tags: mysql, magento2, nco

I am trying to get a report of our New Customers with First Shipment based on specific Order Types IF the Shipment is between two dates. [Can move the condition to the LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47449778/8754633), but don't know how to ensure that it's the FIRST instance in the sales_shipment table AND matches on conditions. If there's a sales_shipment.created_at record BEFORE my dates AND inside of my dates - the record should NOT be returned.

Here's my example -
Let's say I want to return New Registered Customers since 1/1/2022 that have an Order that Shipped Last Week, but I want only the EARLIEST Shipment Record that matches (in the event that there could be multiple shipments) from my BETWEEN

`sales_shipment.created_at`

dates. If there is a Shipment BEFORE my BETWEEN Dates, it shouldn't be returned in this report.

I've removed some table-specific data to make them more general for this example (so you can ignore if some of my "company.field_name" in the report are FROM "company" - they aren't actually in my real tables.

Haven't been able to get

`MIN(sales_shipment.created_at)`

to work.

This is my SQL Query that returns Shipments BEFORE my  sales shipment created at BETWEEN date ranges.

```
SELECT DISTINCT company.entity_id, company_name, company.status, customer_entity_datetime.value AS "Creation Date", legal_name AS 'Company Legal Name', company_email, vat_tax_id, reseller_id, comment, company.telephone AS 'Phone Number', company.country_id AS 'Country', directory_country_region.default_name AS 'State/Province', postcode AS 'Zip', city, company.customer_group_id AS 'Group/Shared Catalog', street AS 'Street Address', super_user_id, customer_entity.firstname, customer_entity.lastname, customer_entity_varchar.value AS "Job Title", customer_entity.email, customer_industry.industry, customer_industry.segment, customer_industry.category, company.accountmanager_id, accountmanager.name, company.accountcoordinator_id, account_coordinator.name, company_credit.currency_code AS 'Credit Currency', company_credit.balance AS 'Outstanding Balance', company_credit.credit_limit, sales_order.created_at AS 'First Order Date', sales_order.increment_id, sales_order.quote_id, quote.order_type, sales_shipment.created_at as 'Ship Date'
FROM company
LEFT JOIN company
    ON company.company_id = company.entity_id
LEFT JOIN customer_entity
    ON customer_entity.entity_id = company.super_user_id
LEFT JOIN company_credit
    ON company_credit.company_id = company.entity_id
LEFT JOIN company_payment
    ON company_payment.company_id = company.entity_id
LEFT JOIN customer_industry
    ON customer_industry.company_id = company.entity_id
LEFT JOIN directory_country_region
    ON directory_country_region.region_id = company.region_id
LEFT JOIN accountmanager
    ON accountmanager.accountmanager_id = company.accountmanager_id
LEFT JOIN account_coordinator
    ON account_coordinator.id = company.accountcoordinator_id
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_datetime
    ON customer_entity_datetime.entity_id = customer_entity.entity_id AND customer_entity_datetime.attribute_id = '495'
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar
    ON customer_entity_varchar.entity_id = customer_entity.entity_id AND customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = '395'
LEFT JOIN sales_order
    ON sales_order.customer_id = company.super_user_id
LEFT JOIN quote
    ON quote.quote_id = sales_order.quote_id
LEFT JOIN sales_shipment
    ON sales_shipment.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id
WHERE customer_entity_datetime.value BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2023-04-22'
    AND sales_shipment.created_at BETWEEN '2023-04-16' AND '2023-04-22'
    AND quote.order_type = 'order' OR 'stock' OR 'order_fulfillment'
ORDER BY company.company_name;
```

This is my query that limits my customer created at to the same range as the shipment, which means I could be losing customer in this report that have a first shipment from last week if their account was created before last week.

```
SELECT DISTINCT company.entity_id, company_name, company.status, customer_entity_datetime.value AS "Creation Date", legal_name AS 'Company Legal Name', company_email, vat_tax_id, reseller_id, comment, company.telephone AS 'Phone Number', company.country_id AS 'Country', directory_country_region.default_name AS 'State/Province', postcode AS 'Zip', city, company.customer_group_id AS 'Group/Shared Catalog', street AS 'Street Address', super_user_id, customer_entity.firstname, customer_entity.lastname, customer_entity_varchar.value AS "Job Title", customer_entity.email, customer_industry.industry, customer_industry.segment, customer_industry.category, company.accountmanager_id, accountmanager.name, company.accountcoordinator_id, account_coordinator.name, company_credit.currency_code AS 'Credit Currency', company_credit.balance AS 'Outstanding Balance', company_credit.credit_limit, sales_order.created_at AS 'First Order Date', sales_order.increment_id, sales_order.quote_id, quote.order_type, sales_shipment.created_at as 'Ship Date'
FROM company
LEFT JOIN company
    ON company.company_id = company.entity_id
LEFT JOIN customer_entity
    ON customer_entity.entity_id = company.super_user_id
LEFT JOIN company_credit
    ON company_credit.company_id = company.entity_id
LEFT JOIN company_payment
    ON company_payment.company_id = company.entity_id
LEFT JOIN customer_industry
    ON customer_industry.company_id = company.entity_id
LEFT JOIN directory_country_region
    ON directory_country_region.region_id = company.region_id
LEFT JOIN accountmanager
    ON accountmanager.accountmanager_id = company.accountmanager_id
LEFT JOIN account_coordinator
    ON account_coordinator.id = company.accountcoordinator_id
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_datetime
    ON customer_entity_datetime.entity_id = customer_entity.entity_id AND customer_entity_datetime.attribute_id = '495'
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar
    ON customer_entity_varchar.entity_id = customer_entity.entity_id AND customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = '395'
LEFT JOIN sales_order
    ON sales_order.customer_id = company.super_user_id
LEFT JOIN quote
    ON quote.quote_id = sales_order.quote_id
LEFT JOIN sales_shipment
    ON sales_shipment.customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id
WHERE customer_entity_datetime.value BETWEEN '2023-04-16' AND '2023-04-22'
    AND sales_shipment.created_at BETWEEN '2023-04-16' AND '2023-04-22'
    AND quote.order_type = 'order' OR 'stock' OR 'order_fulfillment'
ORDER BY company.company_name;
```

Comment: Conditions for a table in `LEFT JOIN` should be in the `ON` clause, not `WHERE`. Otherwise, when there's no match, the values will be `NULL` and the condition won't match.