# mySQL condition if LEFT OUTER JOIN table contains a value in a column

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two database tables: one with user IDs and one containing user metadata (with multiple rows related to the same user ID).

`users` table structure example

| id | USERNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user 1 |
| 2 | user 2 |
| 3 | user 3 |

`users_meta` data structure example

| meta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | key1 | a |
| 2 | 1 | key2 | b |
| 3 | 2 | key1 | d |
| 4 | 3 | key1 | e |
| 5 | 3 | key2 | f |

I'd like query whether a user has got a metadata database row.

```
 SELECT * FROM users 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN users_meta ON users.id = users_meta.user_id
 WHERE users_meta.meta_key != "key2"
 GROUP BY id 
 ORDER BY id ASC 
 LIMIT 0, 100
```

How do I query to get the user id `2` not having a meta value related to `key2`?

Comment: I don't see in your question where you *"already tried using the EXIST statement, but probably in the wrong way"*

Comment: if you're using left outer join, wouldn't the columns from users_meta be blank? you could consider changing one of those columns to for example `nvl( ... , 'no metadata')`

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please add sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Is it correct: you want to exclude all users that have an associated "value to exclude" meta_key, and then include only if they have either the "val1" or "val2" meta_key?

Comment: In a LEFT JOIN, conditions on the second table must be in the `ON` clause. Putting it in the `WHERE` clause will filter out all rows in the first table that have no match. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449631/return-default-result-for-in-value-regardless/47449788#47449788

Comment: Thanks for your comment guys: actually it is much more complex than how I described. The mySQL code is dynamically created by a PHP framework (a sort of WP_query() clone). I simplified the query in the example I pasted hoping it would be easily understandable by you all. However including also the wrapping query is surely confusing, I have edited my post, adding database structure examples and what I want to achieve precisely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Kukuh Gumilang for your reply, it put me somehow on the right track to code a shorter and better solution, perfectly adapting to my complex framework.

The solution was literally as simple as adding a new join and a condition

```
SELECT id, username FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_meta as ume ON users.id = ume.user_id AND ume.meta_key = 'meta-key-to-check'
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_meta as um0 ON users.id = um0.user_id
WHERE 
    (um0.meta_val = 'meta1' AND um0.meta_value IN ('val1', 'val2')) AND
    AND ume.meta_val IS NULL /* or NOT NULL to check for existing metas */
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I use sub queries, union, and query from query.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        (SELECT users_meta.id FROM users_meta WHERE users_meta.user_id = users.id AND users_meta.meta_key = 'key1') AS meta_id,
        users.id AS user_id,
        users.username,
        'key1' AS meta_key,
        (SELECT users_meta.meta_val FROM users_meta WHERE users_meta.user_id = users.id AND users_meta.meta_key = 'key1') AS meta_val
    FROM
        users
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        (SELECT users_meta.id FROM users_meta WHERE users_meta.user_id = users.id AND users_meta.meta_key = 'key2') AS meta_id,
        users.id AS user_id,
        users.username,
        'key2' AS meta_key,
        (SELECT users_meta.meta_val FROM users_meta WHERE users_meta.user_id = users.id AND users_meta.meta_key = 'key2') AS meta_val
    FROM
        users
) AS SRC
WHERE
    meta_val IS NULL
ORDER BY
    user_id
```