# show count 0 in between dates if date not present

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT d.datefield AS DateOfSale, COUNT(s.product_id) AS Sales
FROM calendar d
LEFT Join products s ON s.product_possibleCloseDate = d.datefield 
WHERE s.product_ClientId=483 AND d.datefield BETWEEN '2023-07-12' AND '2023-10-10'
GROUP BY DateOfSale;
```

This is the query I am giving but it only returning two dates while the calendar table has all dates present. It is not giving all the date with count 0 where no data present in the products table

I want

```
2023-07-12 0
2023-07-13 0
------------
2023-07-24 1
```

Currently the result coming is shown in this screenshot:

[image: result]

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) . Sample source data from each table would be a sensible thing to provide, so we can predict what the SQL code will do with it. An actual SQLFiddle with that in it would be even nicer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range). for mysql 8, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59432320/17389)

Comment: Move `AND s.product_ClientId=483` into the `ON` condition.

Comment: @ysth They're already filling in the missing dates with the `calendar` table. The problem is with the `WHERE` condition filtering out those rows.

Comment: @Barmar tell me the query which you are suggesting

Comment: @ysth no this question is not giving me exact results

Comment: Change `ON s.product_possibleCloseDate = d.datefield` to `ON s.product_possibleCloseDate = d.datefield AND s.product_ClientId = 483` and remove that condition from `WHERE`.

Comment: Isn't that fix explained in the linked question?

Comment: @Barmar it will giving results from 2012 but i need results from 2023 itself

Comment: `d.datefield BETWEEN '2023-07-12' AND '2023-10-10'` limits the results to those 3 months.

Comment: I was talking about the first link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449631/return-default-result-for-in-value-regardless