# MySQL query with many to many to one relationship

Tags: mysql

I have a bit of a complex data structure I'm working with, and have not been able to figure out a single query to get all the information I need. I have the following tables:

**User**

| ID | ... |
| --- | --- |
| 24 | ... |

etc.

**company**

| ID | ... |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | ... |

etc.

*organization**

| ID | company_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 75 | 13 | ... |

Where the company ID is a foreign key to the Company, etc.

**street**

| ID | organization_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 75 | ... |

Where the organization ID is a foreign key to the Organization, etc.

**building**

| ID | street_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 8 | ... |

Where the street ID is a foreign key to the Street, etc.

**floor**

| ID | building_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 19 | ... |

Where the building ID is a foreign key to the Building, etc.

**unit**

| ID | floor_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 34 | ... |

Where the floor ID is a foreign key to the Floor, etc.

**user_unit**

| ID | user_id | unit_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 24 | 99 | ... |

Where the user ID is a foreign key to the User, etc.

So far, all straight forward, can get the user, and their associated information all the way up to company with joins. Where this gets complicated is I have customizable attributes in a table like this:

**entity_attribute**

| ID | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | User Note | This is a string Note |

**entity_attribute_mapping**

| ID | type | entity_id | attribute_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | USER | 24 | 55 |
| 3 | ORGANIZATION | 75 | 55 |
| 4 | COMPANY | 13 | 55 |

attribute_id is a foreign key to the attribute table, and the entity_id is queried based on what the entity is, a user, organization, company, etc. Allowing the same user that belongs to multiple companies, organizations, etc. via the user_unit table to have multiple unique notes based on which organization, and company they are in.

This is where I am unable to figure out the appropriate query.

I've attempted something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `user_unit` ON user_unit.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN `unit` ON unit.id = user_unit.unit_id
LEFT JOIN `floor` ON floor.id = unit.floor_id
LEFT JOIN `building` ON building.id = floor.building_id
LEFT JOIN `street` ON street.id = building.street_id
LEFT JOIN `organization` ON organization.id = street.organization_id 
LEFT JOIN `company` ON company.id = organization.company_id
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute_mapping` uam1 ON uam1.entity_id = user.id AND uam1.type = "USER"
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute_mapping` uam2 ON uam2.entity_id = organization.id AND uam2.type = "ORGANIZATION"
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute_mapping` uam3 ON uam3.entity_id = company.id AND uam3.type = "COMPANY"
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute` eanote ON eanote.id = uam1.attribute_id AND eanote.id = uam2.attribute_id AND eanote.id = uam3.attribute_id
WHERE organization.id = 1 ...
```

This obviously doesn't work, and I've tried some variations of it, including using sub queries, but at best I only get back users that have notes in the `entity_attribute` table, rather than all users whether or not they have notes. My current solution is to grab all the users without joining `entity_attribute_mapping` or `entity_attribute` and then programmatically looping through the returned users, and doing individual requests for the notes. This does not scale though, and hundreds or thousands of users creates too many queries/requests. Additionally, there are expected to be more attributes than just notes, so they may have notes, titles, etc. and would need to be able to update the query to pull them as well.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
adjusted the ID values to be clearer what was pointing where

Comment: ...why so many JOINs? (you can't use `SELECT *` because you'll have duplicate column names...)

Comment: @Dai I don't do `SELECT *` in the actual query, but there are far too many fields to include for the sake of the question. And what do you mean by why so many joins? How else would you get all the associated information?

Comment: What other conditions do you have in `WHERE`? If you have any conditions on tables that might not have a matching row, those conditions should be in the corresponding `ON`, not `WHERE`.

Comment: I wonder about this: `eanote.id = uam1.attribute_id AND eanote.id = uam2.attribute_id AND eanote.id = uam3.attribute_id`. Does the note really have to match all 3 rows in `enttity_attribute_mapping`?  Or should this use `OR` rather than `AND`?

Comment: Avoid using `LEFT JOIN` if you know that there will always be a match. `INNER JOIN` has better performance. And make sure you have indexes on all the columns you're joining on.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the pointers. Other conditions for where are `active` values in the `user_unit`, `organization`, and `company` tables, sometimes more from other tables as well. As for the `AND` vs `OR` yes it needs to be `AND`, the note is unique to the user/organization/company combination. There likely could be optimization on the join types, I'm trying to build on existing queries.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449631/return-default-result-for-in-value-regardless/47449788#47449788

Answer (score 0):

Your data model seems excessively complicated, but I am not privy to all your requirements. That being said it appears to me that the sequence of joins needs revision to this:

```
FROM `user`
/* these are necessary to arrive at organization.id & company.id */
INNER JOIN `user_unit`      ON user.id = user_unit.user_id
INNER JOIN `unit`           ON user_unit.unit_id = unit.id
INNER JOIN `floor`          ON unit.floor_id = floor.id
INNER JOIN `building`       ON floor.building_id = building.id
INNER JOIN `street`         ON building.street_id = street.id
INNER JOIN `organization`   ON street.organization_id = organization.id
INNER JOIN `company`        ON organization.company_id = company.id
```

AND: that all of those tables must supply a valid value before you can arrive at organization and company.

Then the entity attribute mapping (or "custom attributes") might not exist in some cases so left joins appear appropriate I believe:

```
/* custom attributes */
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute_mapping` uam1 ON uam1.entity_id = user.id AND uam1.type = "USER"
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute_mapping` uam2 ON uam2.entity_id = organization.id AND uam2.type = "ORGANIZATION"
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute_mapping` uam3 ON uam3.entity_id = company.id AND uam3.type = "COMPANY"
```

Note you have confirmed that ALL THREE of those attributes MUST EXIST to arrive at the possibility of any eanotes. However, if you are also checking for some other attributes of these notes then include those as join conditions (see example):

```
/* requires that all nominated  custom attributes to present */
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute` eanote ON uam1.attribute_id = eanote.id
                                   AND uam2.attribute_id = eanote.id
                                   AND uam3.attribute_id = eanote.id
                                   AND eanote.active = 'Yes' /* example */
```

Having moved most joins from left to inner then the only provided where condition should be OK.

```
SELECT
      user.*
    , organization.id   as organization_id
    , company.id        as company_id
    , eanote.value      as user_note
FROM `user`
/* these are necessary to arrive at organization_id & company_id */
INNER JOIN `user_unit`      ON user.id = user_unit.user_id
INNER JOIN `unit`           ON user_unit.unit_id = unit.id
INNER JOIN `floor`          ON unit.floor_id = floor.id
INNER JOIN `building`       ON floor.building_id = building.id
INNER JOIN `street`         ON building.street_id = street.id
INNER JOIN `organization`   ON street.organization_id = organization.id
INNER JOIN `company`        ON organization.company_id = company.id
/* custom attributes */
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute_mapping` uam1 ON uam1.entity_id = user.id AND uam1.type = "USER"
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute_mapping` uam2 ON uam2.entity_id = organization.id AND uam2.type = "ORGANIZATION"
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute_mapping` uam3 ON uam3.entity_id = company.id AND uam3.type = "COMPANY"
/* requires that all nominated  custom attributes to present */
LEFT JOIN `entity_attribute` eanote ON uam1.attribute_id = eanote.id
                                   AND uam2.attribute_id = eanote.id
                                   AND uam3.attribute_id = eanote.id
                                   AND eanote.active = 'Yes' /* example */                                 
WHERE organization.id = 1 
      /* this is OK if using inner joins as shown */
```

ps: I think you may need a foreign key to user table in the organization table and THEN you would not need so many tables to be inner joined. e.g:

```
SELECT
      user.id           as user_id
    , organization.id   as organization_id
    , company.id        as company_id
FROM `user`
/* new foreign key required for this */
INNER JOIN `organization`   ON user.organization_id = organization.id
INNER JOIN `company`        ON organization.company_id = company.id
/* now these become optional */
LEFT JOIN `user_unit`      ON user.id = user_unit.user_id
LEFT JOIN `unit`           ON user_unit.unit_id = unit.id
LEFT JOIN `floor`          ON unit.floor_id = floor.id
LEFT JOIN `building`       ON floor.building_id = building.id
LEFT JOIN `street`         ON building.street_id = street.id
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is quite an old schema, and there's a lot of business logic in here requiring the complex tables. I tried changing everything to inner joins except for the attributes as you suggested, but then when I join on 2 or more instances of entity_attribute_mapping I end up getting 25 line copies of each user, etc. My where includes organization id, and a user_unit.active check.

Comment: Your "sample data" consists only of "1" in all places - so its hard to find any subtleties. What role does `entity_attribute_mapping`.`attribute_id` play? If the joins to `entity_attribute_mapping` produce unexpected repetition in the result that usually means we are missing something in the joins. Is there anything else in that table that might be used in the joins?

Comment: I suppose I could change the numbers from 1s to be more clear. The ‘entity_attribute_mapping’ table uses the user ID, the organization ID, and the company ID to link an attribute to a user/org/company combo. The ‘entity_attribute_mapping’.’attribute_id’ is used to link to the value in the ‘attribute’ table.

Comment: There has to be a reason for the unwanted multiplication of rows, this will be due to one or more joins (and the data being joined). Without more information I cannot tell you where it is. Just run the query removing a join each time until you can identify which join was the cause of the unwanted rows.

Comment: When I include a single `LEFT` `JOIN` `entity_attribute_mapping`, it returns correctly. When I add a second/third they return multiples. I did update my examples with different IDs to be clearer

Comment: take a look here: https://dbfiddle.uk/GhB6ApM0 depending on how you join  entity_attribute_mapping I get either 3 rows or 1 row. Can you perhaps tweak this fiddle to replicate your unwanted rows problem?