JOIN(left or inner) and WHERE Internal Operation Process Principle(mysql)
I was wondering how join and where apply when MySQL query statement runs.
If anyone knows well, please help me.
[Example]

query: select a.id, a.name, b.id from a left join b on a.b_id = b.id where a.name = 'cale' and b.no = 10
Number of data: 100 for a and 3,000 for b
Indexes are applied to b_id, a.name and b.no
Number of data according to conditions: 10 for conditions a (a.name = 'cale'), and 20 for conditions b (b.no = 10)

[Question]

Is join and where clause applied in the order I think below?


Table A located in from access to the driving table
Find the scale that is the condition of the table A. Extract 10 out of 100 results here
Access table B, which is a driven table
Find no, which is the condition of B. Extract 20 out of 3,000 results here
10*20 = 200 loops in total


Or if i look for the data, the processing order is usually from -> join -> where ...
then I read the table as many as 100(a)*3,000(b) first, and then I wonder if the where clause is applied as a filter.

I am curious about the order of processing the query.

query: select a.id, a.name, b.id from a left join b on a.b_id = b.id where a.name = 'cale' and b.no = 10 - the last condition in WHERE expression converts LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN. Is join and where clause applied in the order I think below? SQL is declarative language, so the particular query execution may differ from formal clause execution ordering. So the answer is "unpredictable", i.e. "maybe yes, maybe no, and if this is yes today then this may be no tomorrow". See query execution plan.

Thank you for your answer. So, is it possible to apply both of the methods I asked depending on the situation?

We cannot predict. We can look at the execution plan which will show what operations sequence will be performed in current data state.

Conceptually, the WHERE condition on table b is applied after the left join. So rows in a that have no match in b will be filtered out, because they'll have b.no = NULL, and NULL = 10 is never true.

That's why conditions on the left joined table should be put in the ON clause, not WHERE. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449631/return-default-result-for-in-value-regardless/47449788#47449788
