PHP MySql search combining results from two columns
I am creating an aircraft listing site and im trying to build in a search feature. Below is the MySql search query that is working well. However; if I search "cessna" I get all the Cessna's that come from listings_aircraft.make and if I search "172" I get all the 172s that come from listings_aircraft.model. But if I search "Cessna 172" I get zero results. How would I modify my query to look for both Cessna and 172 combining the listings_aircraft.make and listings_aircraft.model search together if there is a match in both? Thanks in advance.
  $query = "SELECT listing_control.*, 
    listings_aircraft.year, listings_aircraft.make, listings_aircraft.model, 
    listings_aircraft.price, listings_aircraft.callforprice, 
    listings_aircraft.about, listings_aircraft.aircraft_location
    FROM listing_control
    LEFT JOIN listings_aircraft
    ON listings_aircraft.id = listing_control.listing_id 
    WHERE listings_aircraft.make LIKE '%{$search}%'
    OR listings_aircraft.model LIKE '%{$search}%'
    OR listings_aircraft.about LIKE '%{$search}%' 
    OR listings_aircraft.registration LIKE '%{$search}%' 
    AND NOT listing_control.listing_status = 'draft' 
    AND NOT listing_control.listing_status = 'sold'
    AND NOT listing_control.listing_status = 'expired'
    ORDER BY listing_control.date_created DESC";


You'll have to split your search input into individual terms, and then search for matches for either of the parts, in all relevant columns. WHERE (listings_aircraft.make LIKE '%Cessna%' or listings_aircraft.make LIKE '%172%') OR (listings_aircraft.model LIKE '%Cessna%' OR listings_aircraft.model LIKE '%172%') OR ... The (...) are of course not strictly necessary, when everything is joined by OR, but I would keep them for better readability.

You can combine all those AND NOT into AND listing_control.listing_status NOT IN (...)

Always use parentheses when you mix AND and OR conditions, as the default precedence is often not what you expect (AND has higher precedence than OR, so you're not applying the listing_status condition when make, model, or about match the search string).

When you use LEFT JOIN, the conditions on the second table should be in the ON clause, not WHERE. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449631/return-default-result-for-in-value-regardless/47449788#47449788

Thank you for your help Barmar! I think I have it worked out

Does this answer your question? How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?

I was able to get this search query working exactly how I wanted with the following code. Hope this helps someone else:
$search = trim($clean['search_input']);
if (strlen($search) < 3) { die(); }

$searchTerms = explode(' ', $search); 
$searchCondition = []; 

foreach ($searchTerms as $term) { 
    $term = '%' . $term . '%'; $searchCondition[] = "
    (listings_aircraft.make LIKE '{$term}' OR listings_aircraft.model 
    LIKE '{$term}' OR listings_aircraft.about LIKE '{$term}')"; 
} 

$searchCondition = implode(' AND ', $searchCondition);  

$query = "SELECT listing_control.*,  listings_aircraft.year, 
    listings_aircraft.make, listings_aircraft.model,  
    listings_aircraft.price, listings_aircraft.callforprice,  
    listings_aircraft.about, listings_aircraft.aircraft_location FROM 
    listing_control LEFT JOIN listings_aircraft ON 
    listings_aircraft.id = listing_control.listing_id  WHERE 
    ($searchCondition) AND NOT listing_control.listing_status = 'draft'  
    AND NOT listing_control.listing_status = 'sold' 
    AND NOT listing_control.listing_status = 'expired' 
    ORDER BY listing_control.date_created DESC";

