# Postgres default aggregation value for empty row

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, outer-join

I have written a query that's doing an aggregation of X.

It starts from this week's Monday up to current day.

```
select 
  extract(dow from time_sent) days
  , count(id)
from messages
where time_sent between date_trunc('week', now()) and now()
group by days
order by days;
```

I would like a hint on how to set a default value for Monday when no row was added on Monday.

ie, 
Monday was empty, so I'm getting this:

```
[ anonymous { day: 2, count: '1' },
  anonymous { day: 3, count: '1' },
  anonymous { day: 4, count: '1' },
  anonymous { day: 5, count: '1' },
  anonymous { day: 6, count: '1' } ]
```

Expected result:

```
[ anonymous { day: 1, count: '0' },
  anonymous { day: 2, count: '1' },
  anonymous { day: 3, count: '1' },
  anonymous { day: 4, count: '1' },
  anonymous { day: 5, count: '1' },
  anonymous { day: 6, count: '1' } ]
```

Edit: Add table structure and sample output.

```
id | time_sent 
1  | 2018-01-13 15:26:21.443828+08
2  | 2018-01-12 15:26:21.44755+08
3  | 2018-01-11 15:26:21.459208+08
4  | 2018-01-10 15:26:21.440648+08
5  | 2018-01-09 15:26:21.457262+08
```

Query #1:

```
select 
  coalesce(extract(dow from time_sent), d) days
  , count(message_batch_id)
from generate_series(0,6) d
left join messages 
on d = extract(dow from time_sent)
where time_sent between date_trunc('week', now()) and now()
group by days
order by days;
```

Query #1 output:

```
days | count
2    | 1
3    | 1
4    | 1
5    | 1
6    | 1
```

Edit: I need to clarify that the `messages` table didn't have any row entry on Monday.

Edit:

For some reason, this query returns the row structure that I wanted:

```
select 
    extract(dow from d.*) days, 
    count(id) 
from GENERATE_SERIES(DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', NOW()), NOW(), '1 
DAY'::INTERVAL) d
left outer join messages m
on m.time_sent::DATE = d
group by days
order by days;
```

Comment: Re your edit: 1. Read a definition of left join. 2. If that's a solution, please post as an answer & accept after the minimal wait. If it's not a solution, why is it there? What does "row structure" mean? PS It's good to give all that info, but the format is not useful as runnable code. [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select 
  coalesce(extract(dow from time_sent),d) days
  , count(id)
from generate_series(0,6) d
left outer join messages on d = extract(dow from time_sent)
where time_sent between date_trunc('week', now()) and now()
group by days
order by days;
```

(did not test)

Comment: I'm getting the same result :( . The returned row doesn't include Monday(1).

Comment: is it an empty row,or just no row? editted a little - please try again

Comment: Sorry. I'm kinda new with postgres. It's no row at all.

Comment: I tried the updated query. I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: well question and answer seem obvious. if it does not help, please update your post with structure and data sample. I don't see what could be wrong

Comment: left join and `left outer join` are really different :) `outer ` is meant to solve your problem, not `left`

Comment: I tried using `left outer join` but still no luck, it's still showing the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The predicate can't extend the rows. You have to generate the dates with `GENERATE_SERIES` and join this with `messages`:

```
SELECT extract(dow from time_sent) days, coalesce(count(id), 0)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', NOW()), NOW(), '1 DAY'::INTERVAL) d 
    LEFT JOIN messages ON time_sent::DATE = d
GROUP BY days
ORDER BY days;
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result. Monday(1) is still not included.

Comment: Sorry, you need a left join.

Comment: I'm getting the result for a dummy Monday, but the but instead of getting 1 as the days value, I'm getting NULL.

Comment: `COALESCE` will help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this return the result that I'm expecting.
ie,

Returns the row of the day in a week (even when there's no row entry for that particular day)

```
select 
    extract(dow from d.*) days, 
    count(id) 
from GENERATE_SERIES(DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', NOW()), NOW(), '1 
DAY'::INTERVAL) d
left outer join messages m
on m.time_sent::DATE = d
group by days
order by days;
```