# MYSQL LEFT JOIN not showing all the data

Tags: mysql, json, left-join

I am running this SQL LEFT JOIN query in PHP but it's showing one important column which is **`user_id`** as null which is **not null**.

**MYSQL QUERY**

```
SELECT
      a.*,
      b.*,
      c.*,
      d.*
  FROM ts_users_skills a
  LEFT JOIN ts_students_log b
      ON a.`user_id` = b.`user_id`
  LEFT JOIN ts_students_info c
      ON a.`user_id` = c.`user_id`
  LEFT JOIN `geo_records` d
      ON a.`user_id` = d.`user_id`
  WHERE (a.`skillsTeach` = '$skill_1' OR a.`skillsTeach` = '$skill_2'
      OR a.`skillsTeach` = '$skill_3')
  GROUP BY a.`user_id`;
```

**JSON output**

```
    {
    "status": "success",
    "nearby_teachers": [
        {
            "user_id": null,
            "skillsTeach": "PHP",
            "email": "praveenkumarkp666@gmail.com",
            "country_code": "91",
            "username": "praveenkum",
            "name": "Procusa Founder",
            "gender": "M",
            "birthday": "1997-02-25",
            "location": "Bhubaneswar"
        },
        {
            "user_id": null,
            "skillsTeach": "marketing",
            "email": "ashok@procusa.in",
            "country_code": "91",
            "username": "ashok",
            "name": "Ashok the founder 2",
            "birthday": "1993-11-18",
            "location": "Bhubaneswar"
        },
        {
            "user_id": null,
            "skillsTeach": "html",
            "email": "talspo@gmail.com",
            "country_code": "91",
            "username": "talspo",
            "name": "Procusa Founder",
            "gender": "M",
            "birthday": "1997-01-01",
            "location": "Bhubaneswar"

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Which table `user_id` comes from? Show the code where you build the result

Comment: Thanks for your advice on Prepared Statement. I am implementing it.

Comment: ts_students_log is the table where user_id is located as a Primary Key but it is present in almost every table as a Foreign key.

Comment: Can you please show the php code wher you build the result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have several columns `user_id` in different tables.
In your JSON there is only one `user_id` field, it is not clear from which table it is.

It is clear tho, that the data is getting lost at this point, the JSON contains a `user_id` field from a dataset without a `user_id` field filled.

Try using `user_id` from a different table than `ts_users_skills a`.

Comment: *Try using user_id from a different table than ts_users_skills a* how do you know that OP takes user_id from this table without seeing any code?

Comment: Yeah, I got it actually. the geo_records table was the culprit. I removed it and it worked.

Comment: Thank you @DanFromGermany for your time. I am indebted and grateful to you.

Comment: @Jens no code? He shows is SQL statement. I am programing PHP/MySQL for 18 years now, I have seen all errors, I have seen the OPs problem before and the problem and the reason is just logical - you have several fields, some can be NULL because you LEFT JOIN - result: you picked the wrong field (from the RIGHT side of the dataset).

Comment: Thank you again. You people have been of real help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that it returns several columns named user_id. Some of those values, that come from `LEFT JOIN`s, may come up as `NULL`.

When serializing to JSON, where keys are unique, it is likely that the « wrong » field is being chosen, resulting in a `NULL` value.

To solve this, you want to list precisely the fields to retrieve from each table, instead of using `*`. Of course, `user_id` should come from a table that is not `LEFT JOIN`ed :

```
SELECT
  a.user_id, a.field1, a.field2
  b.field11, b.field12
  c.field21, c.field22, c.field23
  d.field31
...
```

**Details**

You are selecting fields using the `*` :

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*,
  c.*,
  d.*
...
```

But your query shows that you have multiple fields named `user_id` :

```
...
LEFT JOIN ts_students_log b
  ON a.`user_id` = b.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN ts_students_info c
  ON a.`user_id` = c.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `geo_records` d
  ON a.`user_id` = d.`user_id`
 ...
```

Comment: yeah I have multiple user_id. let me try.

Comment: This is practically the same as my answer but your explanation is way better understandable