# MySQL Left Join table where joined table can be null, but has where conditions

Tags: mysql, join

What is the best way to go about left joining a table that has specific where conditions that must be met, but at the same time may also be null ?

Example:

```
Select a.*, b.schedule
from Tablea a 
    left join Tableb b on a.subid = b.subid
WHERE 
    b.date > NOW()
    and b.active = 1
```

It is possible that table B is empty, but if it is not empty then only active future schedules should show up.

Comment: My thoughts are something like "left join (select * from Tableb where date > now() and active = 1) b on a.subid = b.subid, but I am not sure if this will work

Comment: You don't say what you want. You don't give the "specific where conditions"; you give wrong code & give only a partial requirement. When clear this will be a faq.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the condition to the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` :

```
Select a.*, b.schedule
from Tablea a 
    left join Tableb b 
    ON a.subid = b.subid
    AND b.date > NOW()
    AND.active = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the condition for left join column in ON clause   otherwise work as inner join

```
    Select a.*, b.schedule
    from Tablea a 
    left join Tableb b on a.subid = b.subid AND  
        b.date > NOW()
        and b.active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this and it worked, i'll keep this up incase anyone else has a better solution but this was what I came up with

```
Select a.*, b.schedule
from Tablea a 
    left join (select * from Tableb where date > NOW() and active = 1) b 
        on a.subid = b.subid
WHERE
```