# How to structure Left join and exclude matching ID. WHERE IS NULL clause not working

Tags: sql, left-join, where-clause, isnull

I'm wanting to select rows from the leftTable that do not have matchings in the rightTable but get the error 'incorrect syntax at WHERE'. It seems like a simple join but I can't get it to work with "WHERE r.id IS NULL".

Am I correct in understanding that a LEFT JOIN / WHERE rightTable.id IS NULL should produce a list of leftTable items that do not have a matching in the rightTable?

```
  SELECT l.*
  INTO #temp_length
  FROM leftTable l
  LEFT JOIN rightTable r
        ON l.id = r.id
        WHERE r.id IS NULL
        AND l.start <= r.start
        AND l.end > r.start
        WHERE l.type IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
        AND l.id IN (SELECT id FROM lookupTable WHERE d_type = 'Z')
        AND l.disabled = 'N'
        AND r.latest = 'Y';
```

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. [ask]

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. An inner join on or where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join". You have that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: That code doesn't even parse. There can only be one where per select.  (Regardless of that particular problem:) Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.) PS That includes DBMS tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try below - you've include one where clause whereas you used two and also move your others conditions except `r.id IS NULL` in `ON` clause

```
SELECT l.*
  INTO #temp_length
  FROM leftTable l
  LEFT JOIN rightTable r
        ON l.id = r.id AND l.start <= r.start
        AND l.end > r.start and l.type IN ('A', 'B', 'C') AND l.id IN (SELECT id FROM lookupTable WHERE d_type = 'Z')
        AND l.disabled = 'N'
        AND r.latest = 'Y'
        WHERE r.id IS NULL
```