# Return Zero Counts with Filtered GroupBy Query

Tags: sql

I have a `Mail` table containing a list of emails and their content, linked to a `Sender` table that contains personal information about the sender.
I want to build a query that will give me the number of emails sent by each person in the `Sender` table, including those that have never sent any emails.

Thanks to similar questions on SO, I managed to put together the following query which does the job :

```
"SELECT Sender.name, COUNT(Mail.sender_id) FROM Sender LEFT OUTER JOIN Mail ON Mail.sender_id = Sender.id GROUP BY Sender.name"
```

And gives me:

```
[('Jack', 1), ('Jill', 10), ('John', 0)]
```

Now the problem is that I want to add an additional filter, e.g. to only select the counts from the time period that is of interest to me. So I simply added a filter on the Mail collection to the query:

```
SELECT Sender.name, COUNT(Mail.sender_id) FROM Sender LEFT OUTER JOIN Mail ON Mail.sender_id = Sender.id WHERE Mail.reception_date >= '2017-01-01' GROUP BY Sender.name
```

But now, the results do not contain the empty values anymore.

```
[('Jack', 1), ('Jill', 10)]
```

I've tried to move the filtering of the emails to a subquery following advice I found on here:

```
SELECT Sender.name, COUNT(Mfil.sender_id) FROM (SELECT * FROM MAIL WHERE Mail.reception_date >= '2017-01-01') AS Mfil LEFT JOIN Sender ON Mfil.sender_id = Sender.id GROUP BY Sender.name
```

But I still get the same results:

```
[('Jack', 1), ('Jill', 10)]
```

I am a bit at loss regarding what may be causing this and how I could rephrase the query to retrieve the elements whose count is equal to zero when I use the filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT s.name, COUNT(m.sender_id)
FROM Sender s LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Mail m
     ON m.sender_id = s.id AND
        m.reception_date >= '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY s.name;
```

You want to keep all senders (presumably), so that should be the first table in the `from` clause.