# Issue with Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I have two tables in a master detail layout. I want to select all Active items from the Master Table and detail records only if they meet a condition. But I want all Master table items no matter id a detail record exists or not.

My tables look like:
Master - inventoryItem

```
icmasterid  icdescription
WAD110795       WM KIWI-KLIP 3 BEND                    
WAD110796       WM KIWI-KLIP 3 BEND (MZ3,4,&6)                    
WAD118806-50    STROLLER VALENCE BACKDRP HINGE                    
WAD118808       IK STROL B DROP MOUNTING HDW    
WAD118942       1" S-HOOK BAG 100
```

Detail - inventoryLine

```
icmasterid  icdetailquantity    pomasterid
WAD110796               -900    NULL
WAD110796                  0    NULL
WAD110796                  0    119450
WAD110796                900    119347
WAD118808                  0    NULL
WAD118808                 34    NULL
WAD118942                  0    NULL
WAD118942                 59    NULL
WAD118942                  0    NULL
WAD118942                -59    NULL
WAD118942                 59    NULL
```

my sql

```
SELECT inventoryitem.icmasterid,
       inventoryitem.icdescription,
       inventoryline.icdetailquantity,inventoryline.pomasterid
FROM  inventoryitem 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN inventoryline ON inventoryitem.icmasterid=inventoryline.icmasterid 
WHERE inventoryitem.icmasterid < 'WAD18' and inventoryitem.icmasterid like 'WAD%' 
ORDER BY inventoryitem.icmasterid
```

The above gives me all items in inventoryitem and their related inventoryline records as expected.

But when I add

```
and inventoryline.pomasterid <> ''
```

I get just two rows.

```
icmasterid  ICdescription                      icdetailquantity   pomasterid
WAD110796   WM KIWI-KLIP 3 BEND (MZ3,4,&6)                  0   119450
WAD110796   WM KIWI-KLIP 3 BEND (MZ3,4,&6)                900   119347
```

What I need is

```
icmasterid     icdescription                      icdetailquantity  pomasterid
WAD110796      WM KIWI-KLIP 3 BEND (MZ3,4,&6)                    0  119450
WAD110796      WM KIWI-KLIP 3 BEND (MZ3,4,&6)                  900  119347
WAD118806-50   STROLLER VALENCE BACKDRP HINGE                  NULL NULL
WAD118808      IK STROL B DROP MOUNTING HDW                    NULL NULL
WAD118942      1" S-HOOK BAG 100                               NULL NULL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DDL & tabular-formatted input initialization.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Tim Biegeleisen's answer I came up with this.

```
SELECT
    ii.icmasterid,
    ii.icdescription,
    ii.icdetailquantity,inventoryline.pomasterid
FROM inventoryitem ii
LEFT JOIN inventoryline il
    ON ii.icmasterid = il.icmasterid AND and inventoryline.pomasterid <> ''
WHERE
    ii.icmasterid < 'WAD18' AND
    ii.icmasterid LIKE 'WAD%' 
ORDER BY
    ii.icmasterid;
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the logic in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    ii.icmasterid,
    ii.icdescription,
    ii.icdetailquantity,inventoryline.pomasterid
FROM inventoryitem ii
LEFT JOIN inventoryline il
     ON ii.icmasterid = il.icmasterid AND
        -- SUBSTRING(ii.icmasterid, 4, 2) < '18' AND
        ii.icmasterid LIKE 'WAD%' 
ORDER BY
    ii.icmasterid;
```

Comment: That was not quite the answer but pointed me to the answer. 
```
SELECT
    ii.icmasterid,
    ii.icdescription,
    ii.icdetailquantity,inventoryline.pomasterid
FROM inventoryitem ii
LEFT JOIN inventoryline il
     ON ii.icmasterid = il.icmasterid AND inventoryline.pomasterid<> ''
WHERE   
                ii.icmasterid < 'WAD18' AND
        ii.icmasterid LIKE 'WAD%' 
ORDER BY
    ii.icmasterid;
```

sorry I could not figure out how to format this.

Comment: Actually I think you need to update your logic which checks the `icmasterid` column.

Comment: No, it is correct. It is there because there are 10,000 plus rows in the table. Checking for  < 'WAD18' is only there to give me testable sample. Your Substring would give me a of not wanted records.  Thanks for your help.