# Left Join returns NULL on matching data

Tags: sql, join, group-by, exists, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I perform simple `LEFT JOIN` between two tables:

A:

```
YR  QTR MTH DAY        DEPT      SALES
2017 2  04  2017-04-01 B         xxxxxx
2017 1  03  2017-03-31 A         xxxxxxxx
2017 1  03  2017-03-31 B         xxxxx
2017 1  03  2017-03-30 A         xxxx
```

Second table (B) I use to bring `QTR_ALT` number

```
YEAR MONTH QTR QTR_ALT
2016 12    4   12
2017 01    1   12
2017 02    1   12
2017 03    1   11
2017 04    2   11
```

Following `LEFT JOIN B ON A.YR = B.YEAR AND A.QTR = B.QTR AND A.MTH=B.MONTH` returns `NULL` for QTR_ALT for `A.DAY BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2017-03-31'`

```
YR   QTR QTR_ALT  MTH DAY         DEPT      SALES
2017 2   11       04  2017-04-02  A         xxxxxx
2017 2   11       04  2017-04-01  A         xxxxxx
2017 2   11       04  2017-04-01  B         xxxxxx
2017 1   NULL     03  2017-03-31  A         xxxxxxxx
2017 1   NULL     03  2017-03-31  B         xxxxx
2017 1   NULL     03  2017-03-30  A         xxxx
```

I tried moving `WHERE` condition to `JOIN` but no luck. How is it possible these dates don't get join even though corresponding record exists in table B?

Full code:

```
    SELECT YEAR(A.DAY) as YR, 
               QUARTER(A.DAY) as QTR, 
               B.QTR_ALT, 
               (REPEAT(0, 2-LENGTH(MONTH(A.DAY))) || MONTH(A.DAY)) MTH,
               A.DAY, 
               A.DEPT, 
               SUM(A.VAL) as SALES

                FROM A
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT  TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(a.DT, - b.Y), 'YYYY') as YEAR,
                                    TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(a.DT, - b.Y), 'MM') as MONTH,
                                    CEIL(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(add_months(a.dt, -b.y), 'MM')) / 3) as QTR,
                                    CEIL(b.y/3) as QTR_ALT

                                    FROM (SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MONTH') as DT) a
                                            CROSS JOIN (SELECT SEQ8()+1 as Y FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 36)) ORDER BY 1) b
                                    ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH)  B

                    ON QUARTER(A.DAY) = B.QTR 
                    AND (REPEAT(0, 2-LENGTH(MONTH(A.DAY))) || MONTH(A.DAY)) = B.MONTH


    WHERE (YEAR(A.DAY) = B.YEAR)
    AND (A.DAY BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2017-03-31')
    AND A.DEPT in  ('A', 'B')

    GROUP BY A.DAY, YEAR(A.DAY),QUARTER(A.DAY),B.QTR_ALT,(REPEAT(0, 2-LENGTH(MONTH(A.DAY))) || MONTH(A.DAY)), DEPT
    ORDER BY A.DAY DESC
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN B ON A.QTR = B.QTR AND A.MTH=B.MONTH
WHERE  A.YR = B.YEAR

Comment: I can't [reproduce](https://rextester.com/TBNV86398) your issue.

Comment: Please show us your complete query

Comment: @Mehrnoosh - no luck also :(

Comment: You should try to simplify your problem down so that your code example is easier to read. You said that your join is "simple" but it isn't - you have a left join with an inner sql query which has itself got a crossjoin inside another subquery which contains a generator... 

I find that by doing this I often solve my own issue anyway.

Comment: @SimonD - I moved the `B` table to a view and it didn't fix the issue. Still I don't understand why my issue didn't occur for same date range in 2017/2018

Comment: It seems that increasing `ROWCOUNT =>   ` does fix the issue

Comment: Note that SEQ8() can have gaps -- use ROW_NUMBER() for gap-free sequences.  Also try LPAD() for more concise leading zeroes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After an OUTER JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS ORDER BY without TOP/LIMIT is a NOOP.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS This code is clearly not minimal. (Always find the first subexpression that doesn't return what you expect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE A (yr number, qtr number, mth text, day date, dept text, sales number);
INSERT INTO A values (2017,2,'04','2017-04-01','B', 10), 
    (2017,1,'03','2017-03-31','A', 11), 
    (2017,1,'03','2017-03-31','B', 20),
    (2017,2,'03','2017-03-30','A', 6);


WITH 
sub_b AS (
    SELECT 
        TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MONTH') AS dt,
        SEQ8() AS s, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s) AS y,
        ADD_MONTHS(dt, - y) as tmp_date,
        TO_CHAR(tmp_date, 'YYYY') AS year,
        --TO_CHAR(tmp_date, 'MM') AS month, -- NOT USED
        --QUARTER(tmp_date) as QTR, -- NOT USED
        CEIL(y/3) as qtr_alt -- this value seems broken
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 36))
)
SELECT a.yr, 
    a.qtr, 
    b.qtr_alt, 
    a.mth,
    a.day, 
    a.dept, 
    SUM(a.sales) AS sales
FROM a
LEFT JOIN sub_b AS b
    ON a.yr = b.year AND date_trunc('month',a.day) = b.tmp_date
WHERE a.day BETWEEN '2016-12-01' AND '2017-03-31'
    AND a.dept in ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
ORDER BY a.day DESC;
```

seems to work as given how I read your code/intent.

Comment: Thanks Simeon! The issue of `NULL` I'm experiencing appears when full range of data is present. In my opinion it seems that snowflake runs both tables simultaneously but since it finishes table scan on first table, he stops second table scan resulting in not generating mapping for latter periods.

Comment: if you join between the tables correctly you should not be able to get nulls in the QTR_ALT version.

Comment: You version of 'quarter calculator' sub-query seems to be working perfectly!

Comment: In my original query if you change `ROWCOUNT` to 40, issue gets resolved also . It seems as if snowflake stops executing subquery when finishes with first table.