# MySQL problem with query with LIKE on a NULL value

Tags: mysql, join, null, concatenation

I have two tables: articles and trade. 
They are `left join` on `articles.tradeid = trade.id`. Not every article has a trade. So there is the value of `articles.tradeid` 0.

When I start a search like:

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN trade ON articles.tradeid=trade.id 
WHERE CONCAT(articles.number,'|',trade.name) LIKE '%12345%'
```

I do not get any results although there is an article with number 12345, but it has a `tradeid` of 0.
Because of the join the value of trade.name is `NULL`.
Anyone a solution?

Comment: what about IFNULL(trade.name,'') ?

Comment: Can you explain how the query should be then?

Comment: just replace trade.name with IFNULL statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: This is not clear about what the problem is or what the desired behaviour is. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) with [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN trade ON articles.tradeid=trade.id 
WHERE CONCAT_WS('|', articles.number, trade.name) 
LIKE '%12345%'
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pZGZrgMH4R6kSrbsweSVT4/1)

Concatenate With Separator is a special form of `CONCAT`. Be careful because it has a different syntax

Comment: This answer was for me the right answer. Now the query worked as expected/hoped. Thank you!