# SQL Request with LEFT JOIN not able to find data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, where-clause

I'm working on my C# project and I have to get data from database thanks to .sql procedures.

**Synthesis :**

Table `ProprietesCourantes` is linked to table `Entite`.

Table `Archive` is linked to table `EntiteArchive`

==> I would like to make a link between `ProprietesCourantes` and `Archive` thanks to field `Libellé`

**Table `ProprietesCourantes`**

I have several tables in my case :

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [IdEntite]
      ,[Libelle]
      ,[EstActif]
      , ...
      , ...
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[ProprietesCourantes]
  WHERE [Libelle] = 'DELTA SERVICE AUTO';
```

[image]

**Table `Entite`**

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [IdEntite]
      ,[TypeEntite]
      ,[CodeEntite]
      ,[TypeCodeEntite]
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[Entite]
  WHERE IdEntite = '165';
```

[image]

**Table `Archive`**

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [IdArchive]
      ,[IdEntite]
      ,[NoteFinale]
      ,[EstValide]
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[Archive]
  WHERE IdEntite = '33' and EstValide = '1';
```

[image]

**Table `EntiteArchive`**

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [IdEntite]
      ,[TypeEntite]
      ,[CodeEntite]
      ,[Libelle]
      ,...
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[EntiteArchive]
```

[image]

MY SQL REQUEST :

```
SELECT
            ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite                                                                    as IdEntite, 
            ProprietesCourantes.Libelle                                                                     as RaisonSociale,
            Entite.CodeEntite                                                                               as IdCMCIC,
            ProprietesCourantes.NomParent                                                                   as NomGN,
            Archive.NoteFinale                                                                              as Cotation,
            Archive.DateValiditeQuestionnaireDeSoutien                                                      as DateValiditeQuestionnaireDeSoutien,
            ProprietesCourantes.CodePays                                                                    as Pays,
            ProprietesCourantes.EstActif                                                                    as Statut,
            CAST(CASE WHEN Entite.CodeEntite = ProprietesCourantes.IdSocMere THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)      as EstMaisonMere,
            ProprietesCourantes.IdCMCICParent                                                               as IdCMCICParent,
            ProprietesCourantesGN.CodeAlgo                                                                  as CodeAlgoParent

    FROM ProprietesCourantes

    LEFT JOIN Archive   ON (Archive.IdEntite  = ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite and Archive.EstValide=1)
    LEFT JOIN Entite ON Entite.IdEntite = ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite
    LEFT JOIN Entite as EntiteGN ON EntiteGN.CodeEntite = ProprietesCourantes.IdCMCICParent
    LEFT JOIN ProprietesCourantes as ProprietesCourantesGN ON ProprietesCourantesGN.IdEntite = EntiteGN.IdEntite

    WHERE Entite.TypeEntite = 1 
        AND   (ProprietesCourantes.Libelle LIKE '%'+'DELTA SERVICE'+'%' )
```

[image]

As you can see : `Cotation` and `DateValiditeQuestionnaireDeSoutien` are NULL because `LEFT JOIN Archive   ON (Archive.IdEntite  = ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite` can't work (different IDEntite).

I tried to replace by this, but it doesn't work, any idea ?

```
LEFT JOIN Archive   ON ((select EntiteArchive.Libelle from EntiteArchive LEFT JOIN Archive ON (EntiteArchive.IdEntite = Archive.IdEntite)) = ProprietesCourantes.Libelle and Archive.EstValide=1)
```

Comment: The condition on `entite` should be in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could you write an exemple to illustrate your sentence ?

Comment: In other words, by stuffing a condition down in the WHERE clause on a table that is left-joined, you are applying it to the entire result set AFTER the joins happen. You are, essentially, turning your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. You, instead, want that filter to happen to your `entite` table BEFORE the join, so either a subquery or just moving the condition to the `ON` clause will suffice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: @philipxy No it was not this issue. I know I have to write a concise question, clear. But in my case, it's not possible to explain my issue and what I want to get without set the context and tables around. Sorry

Comment: The duplicate is a problem with your code. PS You don't clearly explain what result you want or what is wrong with your code. Also: In code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to see how your tables are... could it be possible that Archive table has no rows for IdEntite='165'? Are the two keys of the same format? You are showing the output for IdEntite='165' but the 4 example tables are for 2 different IdEntite. Can you provide more insights?

**Edited:**
For what I understand, you want to join by Libelle field both `ProprietesCourantes` and `Archive` but your join is based on IdEntite?

If so, use an intermediate table join ```...

````
Archive.NoteFinale                                   as Cotation,
Archive.DateValiditeQuestionnaireDeSoutien           as DateValiditeQuestionnaireDeSoutien,
...
LEFT JOIN EntiteArchive ON (EntiteArchive.Libelle = ProprietesCourantes.Libelle )
LEFT JOIN Archive ON (EntiteArchive.IdEntite = Archive.IdEntite)
...
```
````

Comment: Yes it's not easy to show you the database relations. But for the same object named (Libelle field) "DELTA SERVICE AUTO", it has IdEntite = '165' in ProprietesCourantes table and IdEntite = '33' in Archive table.

Comment: It seems to work very well ! It seems to be the good answer :) Thank you ! **EDIT** If I want to join by CodeEntite field it's possible ?

Comment: I changed by this and it works too : 
`LEFT JOIN EntiteArchive ON (EntiteArchive.CodeEntite = (SELECT CodeEntite FROM [dbo].Entite WHERE Entite.IdEntite = ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite))
 LEFT JOIN Archive ON (EntiteArchive.IdEntite = Archive.IdEntite and Archive.EstValide=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Just move the condition on the `let join`ed table `Entite` to the `on` part of the join. Otherwise, it becomes a mandatory condition, and filters out records for which there is no match in `Entite`.

```
SELECT
            ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite                                                                    as IdEntite, 
            ProprietesCourantes.Libelle                                                                     as RaisonSociale,
            Entite.CodeEntite                                                                               as IdCMCIC,
            ProprietesCourantes.NomParent                                                                   as NomGN,
            Archive.NoteFinale                                                                              as Cotation,
            Archive.DateValiditeQuestionnaireDeSoutien                                                      as DateValiditeQuestionnaireDeSoutien,
            ProprietesCourantes.CodePays                                                                    as Pays,
            ProprietesCourantes.EstActif                                                                    as Statut,
            CAST(CASE WHEN Entite.CodeEntite = ProprietesCourantes.IdSocMere THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)      as EstMaisonMere,
            ProprietesCourantes.IdCMCICParent                                                               as IdCMCICParent,
            ProprietesCourantesGN.CodeAlgo                                                                  as CodeAlgoParent    
    FROM ProprietesCourantes    
    LEFT JOIN Archive
        ON  Archive.IdEntite  = ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite 
        AND Archive.EstValide=1)
    LEFT JOIN Entite 
        ON  Entite.IdEntite = ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite 
        AND Entite.TypeEntite = 1 
    LEFT JOIN Entite as EntiteGN 
        ON  EntiteGN.CodeEntite = ProprietesCourantes.IdCMCICParent
    LEFT JOIN ProprietesCourantes as ProprietesCourantesGN 
        ON  ProprietesCourantesGN.IdEntite = EntiteGN.IdEntite
    WHERE ProprietesCourantes.Libelle LIKE '%'+'DELTA SERVICE'+'%'
```

Comment: Ok I understand, but it gives me always both fields to NULL and I have to find a way to JOIN tables in order to get `Cotation` and `DateValiditeQuestionnaireDeSoutien`. Maybe my question was not really clear ? `LEFT JOIN Archive
        ON  Archive.IdEntite  = ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite 
        AND Archive.EstValide=1)` couldn't match

Answer (score 1):

Is `CodeEntite` usable as a join?

```
JOIN [EntiteArchive] ON [Entite].[CodeEntite] =  [EntiteArchive].[CodeEntite] 
JOIN [Archive] ON [EntiteArchive].[IdEntite]  = [Archive].[IdEntite]
```

Comment: Yes it's what I'm trying to do. I wrote this, but it's not a good syntax, just to get the idea : `LEFT JOIN Archive   ON (SELECT CodeEntite FROM EntiteArchive WHERE IdEntite = Archive.IdEntite = SELECT CodeEntite FROM Entite WHERE IdEntite = ProprietesCourantes.IdEntite)`