# SQL query to sum inventory with nested filters (case or if statements?)

Tags: sql, join, group-by, case

I am really new to sql.
I cannot get my query to work right. 
I have two tables joined. I need the query to sum the total qty and if the product is "mask", class is "a" and less than 1000, then sum the qty and if the product is glove and below 10000 then sum the qty else 0 regardless of location. I made a where clause to filter out qty = 0 and is not null

```
SELECT 
m.itemdesc
CASE when i.class = 'a' and i.product = 'mask' and sum(i.qty) < 1000 then sum(i.qty) else 0 end
CASE when i.class = 'a' and i.product = 'glove' and sum(i.qty) < 10000 then sum(i.qty) else 0 end

FROM master as m 
LEFT JOIN inventory as i on m.itemid=i.itemid

WHERE i.location in ('1','2')
AND i.class in ('a')
AND i.product in ('mask','glove')
GROUP BY m.itemid, i.location, i.product
HAVING sum(l.qty_on_hand) > 0 and sum(l.qty_on_hand) is not null
```

TABLE INVENTORY

```
i.location   i.product   i.itemid   i.qty   i.class
1            mask        a          998     a
2            mask        a          1       a
1            mask        b          999     b
2            mask        b          1       b
1            glove       c          99998   a
2            glove       c          1       a
```

TABLE MASTER

```
m.itemid   m.itemdesc
a          KN95
b          3-Ply
c          Latex
```

DESIRED RESULT

```
m.itemdesc   i.qty
KN95         999
Latex        99999
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4707673/3404097), Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a LEFT JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: @ManuelWan . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a join, aggregation, and conditional filtering in the `having` clause:

```
select m.itemdesc, sum(i.qty) sum_qty
from inventory i
inner join master m on m.itemid = i.itemid
group by i.itemid, m.itemdesc, i.product, i.class
having sum(i.qty) < case
    when i.product = 'mask' and i.class = 'a' then 1000
    when i.product = 'glove' and i.class = 'a' then 10000
end
order by m.itemdesc
```

Comment: There are more than 2 locations. I only listed two locations to make it brief so there are two itemdesc and showing qtys in both locations. I need the sum to show one row per itemdesc

Comment: @ManuelWan: this query should work across locations. Please give it a try.

Comment: I ran the query, items are showing twice when both locations are below the minimum qty. It is not summing the qtys together.

Comment: @ManuelWan: it is not about the location. The query produces one row per `(i.itemid, i.product, i.class)` tuple. If the same `itemid` might have different `product` or `class`, then rows are duplicated. Remember that I asked about that as a comment on your question.

Comment: The query is working. I checked the itemid and they have the same `product` and `class` in both `locations`. Its weird the query would separate both locations per item if below the minimum. Is there something wrong with `having sum(i.qty) < case`?

Comment: Well it worked. I woke up this morning and played with spaces etc and the results worked as you said. Thanks