# Can't get expected result using left join and on condition

Tags: mysql, left-join

Running the following scripts, you will get 2 tables with records.

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for data
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data`;
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of data
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('2');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for status
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `status`;
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of status
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `status` VALUES ('1', '0');
INSERT INTO `status` VALUES ('1', '1');
```

Table `data`

```
+--------+--------+
|  id    | more...|
|--------|--------+
|  1     |        |
|  2     |        |
+--------+--------+
```

Table `status`

```
+--------+--------+
|  id    | status |
|--------|--------+
|  1     |  0     |
|  1     |  1     |
+--------+--------+
```

I need select data of table `data` excluded items which status is 0 after refer to `status`.

## Wrong try 1

I write the following SQL, and get the following result. It's not the expected result because the item id=2 is also needed.

`select * from data d LEFT JOIN status s on d.id=s.id where s.status=1`

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  id    |  id1   | status |
|--------|--------|--------+
|  1     |  1     |  1     |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

## Wrong try 2

Then I change `where` to `on`, and get the following result which looks good.

`select * from data d LEFT JOIN status s on d.id=s.id and s.status=1`

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  id    |  id1   | status |
|--------|--------|--------+
|  1     |  1     |  1     |
+--------+--------+--------+
|  2     | (Null) | (Null) |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

## Try 3

Table `status` has two items now. If I delete the item (id=1,status=1) of table `status` , what will be the result ?

`select * from data d LEFT JOIN status s on d.id=s.id and s.status=1`

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  id    |  id1   | status |
|--------|--------|--------+
|  1     | (Null) | (Null) |
+--------+--------+--------+
|  2     | (Null) | (Null) |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

In this case, I expect the item id=1 should not be here . The expected result is

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  id    |  id1   | status |
+--------+--------+--------+
|  2     | (Null) | (Null) |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Why does the item id=1 appear in the result ? Can't it resolve my issue using `on status=1` ?

Comment: Show desired result for provided source data.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. It could be you want items from data where there is no record in status and any item from data where there is no 0 status value in status.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, that's my need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please clarify via edits, not comments. When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first subexpression that doesn't output what you expect (which includes confirming that others all give what you expect) & its input & output. Don't give a bunch of wrong stabs in the dark & a bunch of uninvestigated/researched wonderings & give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) returns **all** the rows of the *left* table.
Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select d.* from data d
where not exists (
  select 1 from status s
  where s.id = d.id and s.status = 0
)
```

Or with `NOT IN`:

```
select * from data 
where id not in (select id from status where status = 0)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4eadcd66107232a1f5326c80ab820f7e).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your two SQL clauses can filter the records of table `data` correctly. If I also need the columns of table `status`, is it possible to do it with a simple way?  `select d.*,s.* from data d` seems not working.

Comment: Do you mean this: `select d.*, s.* 
from data d inner join s
on s.id = d.id 
where d.id not in (select id from status where status = 0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps post your expected answer, but to return values in data where status is not zero:

```
Select id 
from data d
Left join status s on d.id = s.id
Where ((s.status <> 0) or (s.status isnull))
```

Comment: That's not my need. The records that have no status also be included into results.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my issue with the following SQL. I have learned my case is not a typical `LEFT JOIN` scenario, so just putting a condition `status=1` to `where` or `on` can't resolve it directly.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    data d
LEFT JOIN status s ON d.id = s.id
WHERE
    s.status = 1
OR ISNULL(s.status)
```