# How do I get All actors that haven't appeared in R rated films

Tags: sql, join, subquery

[image]

I want to get `All actors  that haven't appeared in R rated films`

It was easy to do with `sub-queries`

```
select *
from actor
where actor_id not in
  (select actor_id
   from actor
     inner join film_actor using (actor_id)
     inner join film using (film_id)
   where rating = 'R');
```

I am unable to do it with `joins` -

I have done this till now -

```
select distinct(a.actor_id), a.first_name, a.last_name
from actor as a
  left join
    (film_actor as fa
       inner join film as f
         on fa.film_id = f.film_id)
  on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
  where f.rating = 'R'
  order by actor_id
```

In the above query I get all the actors who have worked in `R` rated films, but now I am not sure how to get the `non R` rated films

Can someone help me do this with joins?

Comment: Not sure what more information is needed? Whoever asked to close it, it would be helpful if you could comment and ask about it?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Why do you have `INT4` in `film` and `actor`, yet `INT2` in `film_actor`?

Comment: @MatBailie I understand it's incorrect, it' s a DB I picked up somewhere.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? It's not clear here what queries you have do what parts of your overall goal & what things you are stuck at. Are you asking about rewriting joins to use subqueries, or what? PS Re this code, we can't cut & paste & run. Also, if we could, the image would be redundant. But anyway: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @philipxy It was all clear to me...

Comment: @Gautam . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? . [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4707673/3404097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` clauses are applied ***after*** joins.

The implact here is that your `LEFT JOIN` has effectively been turned back in to an `INNER JOIN`:
- The `LEFT JOIN` returns some records with `NULL`s
- The `WHERE` clause excludes the `NULL`s

Instead, you ***must*** filter to the `R` rated films ***before*** the `JOIN` on to the actors table.

```
select distinct(a.actor_id), a.first_name, a.last_name
from actor as a
  left join
    (film_actor as fa
       inner join film as f
         on fa.film_id = f.film_id
         and f.rating = 'R')         -- R Rating filter here
  on a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
  where f.film_id IS NULL            -- where the actor does NOT map to such films
  order by actor_id
```

The `DISTINCT` shouldn't be required either, the join is 1 actor to 0 films, so no duplication.

Also, I find your style very hard to read.  Try spacing things out a bit more, and making the level of indentation wore consistent?

```
SELECT
    a.actor_id,
    a.first_name,
    a.last_name
FROM
  actor   AS a
LEFT JOIN
(
        film_actor   AS fa
    INNER JOIN
        film         AS f
            ON  fa.film_id = f.film_id
            AND f.rating   = 'R'
)
    ON  a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
WHERE
    f.film_id IS NULL
ORDER BY
    a.actor_id
```

Finally, `NOT EXISTS` is often much faster than `NOT IN` for these cases *(anti-semi-joins)*.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    actor
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            film_actor
        INNER JOIN
            film
                USING (film_id)
        WHERE
                film.rating         = 'R'
            AND film_actor.actor_id = actor.id
    )
```

Comment: I was not able to remember how to apply the `R Rating filter`. Thank you this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you know how to find all actors in R-rated films, then SQL subtraction is a good solution.
Select all actors
minus
Select all actors in R-rated files.