# Where condition is negating left join

Tags: sql, laravel, join, eloquent

I currently have this code using Eloquent:

```
CustomerSource::leftJoin("booking", "booking.customer_source_id", "=", "customer_source.id")
->selectRaw("customer_source.text, count(booking.id) as count")
->groupBy("text")
->where([
    ["booking_date", ">=", $from],
    ["booking_date", "<=", $to],
])->get()
```

with $to and $from being dates.

I need the query so that it counts the number of bookings made in a date range for each customer source.

When I remove the where condition, it lists all Customer sources, and the counts of bookings as it should (some can be 0), but when I include the where condition, it treats the query as if the join is an inner join and any customer sources that do not have any related bookings for the date period are not in the result set.

Please could you help me in figuring out the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get what you're looking for by using [whereBetween()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) and feeding in dates:

```
CustomerSource::leftJoin("booking", "booking.customer_source_id", "=", "customer_source.id")
  ->selectRaw("customer_source.text, count(booking.id) as count")
  ->groupBy("text")
  ->whereBetween('booking_date', [$from, $to])
  ->get();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using left join closure.

```
CustomerSource
::leftJoin("booking", function ($join) use ($from, $to){
    $join->on("booking.customer_source_id", "=", "customer_source.id")
        ->whereBetween("booking_date", [$from, $to]);
})
->selectRaw("customer_source.text, count(booking.id) as count")
->groupBy("text")
->get()
```