# Rails 5 left outer join with where() conditions excludes rows from left table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, left-join

I have a Qualifiers table storing various terms used to qualify movies. Some of them have a kind `:tag` or `:pool` and can be `:active` or not. They are attributed to movies through a Movietags relationship table, relatively to an edition, which changes each year.

```rb
class Qualifier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :movies
  has_many :qualifiers, through: :movietags
  has_many :movietags, inverse_of: :qualifier, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end

class Movietag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :edition
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :qualifier
end
```

My goal is to get all the active tags (hence the two scopes) along with their movietags of any given edition (and only those). This query works and does a LEFT OUTER JOIN **but** excludes the qualifiers with movietags not used in the given edition:

```rb
@qualifiers = Qualifier.all_tags.active
      .includes(:movietags)
      .where('movietags.edition_id = ? OR movietags.edition_id IS NULL', @edition_id)
      .references(:movietags)
```

```sql
-- irrelevant parts removed for legibility
SELECT "qualifiers"."id" AS t0_r0, "qualifiers"."kind" AS t0_r1, "qualifiers"."active" AS t0_r2, 
"movietags"."id" AS t1_r0, "movietags"."edition_id" AS t1_r1, "movietags"."movie_id" AS t1_r2, 
"movietags"."qualifier_id" AS t1_r3 FROM "qualifiers" LEFT OUTER JOIN "movietags" ON 
"movietags"."qualifier_id" = "qualifiers"."id" WHERE "qualifiers"."kind" IN ('tag', 'pool') AND 
"qualifiers"."active" = $1 AND (movietags.edition_id = 5 OR movietags.edition_id IS NULL) [["active", "t"]]
```

How can I get **all** the active tags?

I'm looking for a pure Rails solution, I'm aware that direct SQL queries can achieve this (see comments, thanks @philipxy).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: @philipxy thanks for the feedback, but I wanted a Rails way to do it ^^ I'm trying to avoid as much as possible direct SQL queries for legibility and maintenance. I have a working Rails solution for this problem but which requires 2 queries and I was wondering if it could be done in one, but with Rails syntax.