# Include "0" results in COUNT(*) aggregate

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, count

Good morning, I've searched in the forum one doubt that I have but the results that I've seen didn't give me a solution.

I have two tables.

**CARS:**

```
Id    Model
1     Seat
2     Audi
3     Mercedes
4     Ford
```

**BREAKDOWNS:**

```
IdBd   Description         Date         Price      IdCar
1      Engine              01/01/2020   500 €      3
2      Battery             05/01/2020   0 €        1
3      Wheel's change      10/02/2020   110,25 €   4
4      Electronic system   15/03/2020   100 €      2
5      Brake failure       20/05/2020   0 €        4
6      Engine              25/05/2020   400 €      1
```

I wanna make a query that shows the number of breakdowns by month with 0€ of cost.

I have this query:

```
SELECT Year(breakdowns.[Date]) AS YEAR, StrConv(MonthName(Month(breakdowns.[Date])),3) AS MONTH, Count(*) AS [BREAKDOWNS]
FROM cars LEFT JOIN breakdowns ON (cars.Id = breakdowns.IdCar AND breakdowns.[Price]=0)
GROUP BY breakdowns.[Price], Year(breakdowns.[Date]), Month(breakdowns.[Date]), MonthName(Month(breakdowns.[Date]))
HAVING ((Year([breakdowns].[Date]))=[Insert a year:])
ORDER BY Year(breakdowns.[Date]), Month(breakdowns.[Date]);
```

And the result is (if I put year '2020'):

```
YEAR   MONTH       BREAKDOWNS
2020   January     1
2020   May         1
```

And I want:

```
YEAR   MONTH       BREAKDOWNS
2020   January     1
2020   February    0
2020   March       0
2020   May         1
```

Thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried but same result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 0):

The HAVING condition should be in WHERE (otherwise it changes the Outer to an Inner join). But as long as you don't use columns from `cars` there's no need to join it.

To get rows for months without a zero price you should switch to *conditional aggregation* (Access doesn't support Standard SQL CASE, but IIF?).

```
SELECT Year(breakdowns.[Date]) AS YEAR,
   StrConv(MonthName(Month(breakdowns.[Date])),3) AS MONTH,
   SUM(CASE WHEN breakdowns.[Price]=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [BREAKDOWNS]
FROM breakdowns
JOIN cars
  ON (cars.Id = breakdowns.IdCar)
WHERE ((Year([breakdowns].[Date]))=[Insert a year:])
GROUP BY breakdowns.[Price], Year(breakdowns.[Date]), Month(breakdowns.[Date]), MonthName(Month(breakdowns.[Date]))
ORDER BY Year(breakdowns.[Date]), Month(breakdowns.[Date]
```

Comment: Syntax error with your query and with "SUM(IIf(breakdowns.[Price]=0;1;0) AS [BREAKDOWNS]"

Comment: 2nd closing parens is missing: `SUM(IIf(breakdowns.[Price]=0;1;0)) AS [BREAKDOWNS]`