# SQL Not Showing Rows when no record exists in a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, where-clause

I have a clientlist table a payments table and a calls table

I want to return a row consisting of most of the clientlist table the date and amount of last payment and same for date of last call.

I have written a query that almost (so not at all) works .. it works as expected as long as a payment and call exist on the joined tables. if one or other does not exist the query does not return a row.

what i would like is the client data returned regardless of payment and calls data.

```
SELECT clientlist.ID, clientlist.FirstName, clientlist.LastName, clientlist.`Herd Number`, clientlist.Address1, clientlist.Address2, clientlist.Address3, clientlist.County, 
clientlist.postcode, clientlist.Mobile, clientlist.AuditDue AS `Cert Expiry`,p1.dateofpayment,p1.amt ,c1.dateofcall, a1.link,a1.dateOfAudit

FROM agritxtdev.clientlist left join payments p1 

on clientlist.ID=p1.clientnum 

left join calls c1

on clientlist.id= c1.clientnum left join auditdate a1 on a1.client = clientlist.id

where p1.id = (Select MAX(id) from payments p2 where p1.clientnum=p2.clientnum) 

AND c1.id= (Select MAX(id) from calls c2 where c1.clientnum=c2.clientnum) 

order by clientlist.ID
```

I would really appriecate any help ye can give me with this one.

im fairly certain the my issue is in here but im lost as to another approach

```
where p1.id = (Select MAX(id) from payments p2 where p1.clientnum=p2.clientnum) 

AND c1.id= (Select MAX(id) from calls c2 where c1.clientnum=c2.clientnum)
```

thanks in advance Peter

Comment: Move those conditions to the `on` clause.

Comment: Thank you so much ... so simple but my head hurts from hitting the desk ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the issue is with the conditions in the `where` clause. Basically you need to move them to the `on` clause of the respective join. Otherwise the conditions are mandatory, and filter out rows for which the `left join` did not match:

```
select ...
from agritxtdev.clientlist 
left join payments p1 
    on  clientlist.id=p1.clientnum 
    and p1.id = (select max(id) from payments p2 where p1.clientnum=p2.clientnum) 
left join calls c1 
    on  clientlist.id= c1.clientnum 
    and c1.id= (select max(id) from calls c2 where c1.clientnum=c2.clientnum) 
left join auditdate a1 
    on  a1.client = clientlist.id
order by clientlist.id
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend a change of approach , it's not only your problem - it's also a very wasteful proc.

try this :

```
select max(Id) 'IdPay' into #tempPayments from payments group by clientnum
select max(Id) 'IdCalls' into #tempCalls from calls group by clientnum

SELECT your_fields
FROM agritxtdev.clientlist left join #tempPayments p1 
on (clientlist.ID = p1.IdPay OR p1.IdPay IS NULL)
left join #tempCalls c1 on (clientlist.id= c1.IdCalls or c1.IdCalls IS NULL)
left join auditdate a1 on a1.client = clientlist.id

drop table #tempCalls
drop table #tempPayments
```