# SELECT with foreign key with JOIN mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this table of contracts where I have parent contracts and sub contracts. I want to select all the parent contracts with the number of their subordinate contracts.

```
SELECT  
sup.id_contract, sup.parent_id, sup.contractor_name
IFNULL(count(sub.id_contract),0) AS orders
FROM Contracts sub 
LEFT JOIN Contracts sup ON sub.parent_id=sup.id_contract 
where sup.deleted !=1 GROUP BY sup.id_contract;
```

but for me, parent contract it also a contract with parent_id=NULL and its "orders" can be '0'

How can i do that to select also all Contracts with parent_id NULL where amount of orders will be 0?

Comment: `count(sub.id_contract)` -> NULL values are not counted. Also, you should use `left join`..

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and will raise an error with newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: To get true LEFT JOIN result, move the sup.deleted condition from WHERE to ON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that you are searching for is called [left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

```sql
SELECT 
sup.id_contract, sup.parent_id, sup.contractor_name, sup.subject_of_contract, sup.type_of_contract, sup.notice_period, sup.delete_parent_contract, 
d.date,
count(sub.id_contract) AS orders
FROM Contracts sup
LEFT JOIN Contracts sub ON sub.parent_id = sup.id_contract
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(d.date, "%Y-%m-%d")) date, d.id_contract FROM 
    Dates d GROUP BY d.id_contract
) d ON sup.id_contract=d.id_contract 
WHERE sup.deleted != 1
GROUP BY sup.id_contract;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select all the parent contracts with the number of their subordinate contracts.

You should be able to do this using window functions.  The basic idea is to `COALESCE()` the parent id with the contract id and do a count.  This is one more than the number of subcontract, because it includes the parent, so subtract 1:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(c.parent_id, c.id_contract)) - 1 as num_subcontracts
      FROM Contracts c
      WHERE c.deleted <> 1
     ) c
WHERE c.parent_id IS NULL;
```

Actually, you can do this without the `- 1` as well:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             COUNT(c.parent_id) OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(c.parent_id, c.id_contract)) as num_subcontracts
      FROM Contracts c
      WHERE c.deleted <> 1
     ) c
WHERE c.parent_id IS NULL;
```