# When I do left join, I am still not able to get data from left table?

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

The condition is I know the right table does not have all matching records with the left table.

but I am still not able to get data from left table with null from right table

```
select a.sales, b.profit 
from T1 a 
  left join T2 b on a.id = b.id
where b.category = 'office'
  and b.code = '245'
```

because of the where condition of right table, the right table does not have matching records,
without where condition I got the records.

My question is will left table be affected with where condition of right table although using left join to retain the left table records.

Comment: If there are no matches in `T2`, then `b.code = '245'` cannot be true, because `b.code IS NULL`. Move the `WHERE` condition to the join condition

Comment: yes it will be affected. WHERE on the right table converts LEFT JOIN to INNER. I guess you can try to rewrite your query as SELECT A.SALES, B.PROFIT FROM T1 A LEFT JOIN (SELECT X.ID,X.PROFIT FROM T2 X WHERE X.CATEGORY='OFFICE' AND X.CODE='245')B ON A.ID=B.ID

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 4):

Your `WHERE` clause forces the query to only return rows which `b.category` and `b.code` match the required values and so are non-`NULL`; this effectively turns your `JOIN` condition into an `INNER JOIN`.

You want to put the filters in the join condition:

```sql
select a.sales,
       b.profit 
from   T1 a 
       left join T2 b
       on (   a.id = b.id
          AND b.category = 'office'
          AND b.code = '245')
```

Or to pre-filter `T2` in a sub-query:

```sql
select a.sales,
       b.profit 
from   T1 a 
       left join (
         SELECT *
         FROM   T2
         WHERE  category = 'office'
         AND    code = '245'
       ) b
       on a.id = b.id
```