# Hibernate generates cross join instead of left outer join for optional relation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, left-join

I modeled a database relationship in JPA like this:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED) // Required for JPA
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OuterEntity {
    @Id
    private String outerId;

    @JoinColumn(nullable = true)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private InnerEntity inner;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED) // Required for JPA
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InnerEntity {
    @Id
    private String innerId;

    @Column
    private boolean deleted;
}
```

And persisted some test data as follows:

```java
InnerEntity inner = new InnerEntity("inner", false);
OuterEntity outerWithInner = new OuterEntity("outerWithInner", inner);
OuterEntity outerWithoutInner = new OuterEntity("outerWithoutInner", null);
em.persist(inner);
em.persist(outerWithInner);
em.persist(outerWithoutInner);
```

Performing a very simple query using the criteria API successfully gives two results:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<OuterEntity> query = cb.createQuery(OuterEntity.class);
query.from(OuterEntity.class);
System.out.println(em.createQuery(query).getResultList());
// [OuterEntity(outerId=outerWithInner, inner=InnerEntity(innerId=inner, deleted=false)), OuterEntity(outerId=outerWithoutInner, inner=null)]
```

But once I add a filter on the `inner` entity like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<OuterEntity> query = cb.createQuery(OuterEntity.class);
Root<OuterEntity> root = query.from(OuterEntity.class);
query.where(cb.or(cb.isNull(root.get("inner")), cb.isFalse(root.get("inner").get("deleted"))));
```

hibernate generates a `cross join` with `where outerentit0_.innerId_innerId=innerentit1_.innerId` in the resulting SQL in order to access the `inner` entity's table:

```sql
select
    outerentit0_.outerId as outerid1_1_,
    outerentit0_.inner_innerId as inner_in2_1_ 
from OuterEntity outerentit0_
cross join InnerEntity innerentit1_ 
where
    outerentit0_.inner_innerId=innerentit1_.innerId 
    and (
        outerentit0_.inner_innerId is null 
        or innerentit1_.deleted=0
    )
```

This now only returns one entity:

```
[OuterEntity(outerId=outerWithInner, inner=InnerEntity(innerId=inner, deleted=false))]
```

Which is not the result I desire. I expected there to still be two results.

I believe this happens because the filter `outerentit0_.inner_innerId=innerentit1_.innerId` removes the outer entity that has `null` for its `inner`, because using `=` on nulls always evaluates to false.
Note that I explicitly set the join column to nullable and the many-to-one relationship to optional in the JPA-annotations, so I expected JPA to properly handle the null-case instead.

If I add either `root.join("inner", JoinType.LEFT);` or `root.join("inner", JoinType.LEFT);`, I get the correct result because the generated query is using a `left outer join`:

```sql
select
    outerentit0_.outerId as outerid1_1_,
    outerentit0_.inner_innerId as inner_in2_1_ 
from OuterEntity outerentit0_ 
left outer join InnerEntity innerentit1_ 
    on outerentit0_.inner_innerId=innerentit1_.innerId 
where
    outerentit0_.inner_innerId is null 
    or innerentit1_.deleted=0
```

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<OuterEntity> query = cb.createQuery(OuterEntity.class);
Root<OuterEntity> root = query.from(OuterEntity.class);
root.join("inner", JoinType.LEFT);
cb.isFalse(root.get("inner").get("deleted"))));

List<OuterEntity> result = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
System.out.println(result);
// [OuterEntity(outerId=outerWithInner, inner=InnerEntity(innerId=inner, deleted=false)), OuterEntity(outerId=outerWithoutInner, inner=null)]
```

Which is a workable solution I suppose, but I am very confused why hibernate would emit a `cross join`, which is *subtly wrong* for my expectations, the worst kind of wrong. What did I do to cause this behaviour? Am I required to always *explicitly* perform a left outer join when dealing with nullable relations like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Comment: My point is that a particular left join followed by a particular where (and possibly under particular constraints) can be a query whose result is always the same as an INNER/CROSS JOIN WHERE, so Hibernate might generate the SQL that way. However I suspect my comment reasoning re your "filter added" query was wrong in detail so I deleted it. However, I still suspect the problem is the left join and/or "added filter" not doing what you expect. I think it's clear your explanation is not clear, we'll have to disagree. Re input plus output, I mean it would help to also see the DB contents/results.

Comment: @Felk can you submit you solution (`root.join("inner", JoinType.LEFT);`) as an answer? It solved my problem, as id did with yours, and would be more visible that way.