# Fetch Parent Record anyway even if child condition doesn't meet without using ON

Tags: sql, database, join, oracle11g

I have two tables Employee and Address.
One Employee can have multiple Address.
Here I want to fetch 'active employee details' and 'active address details' of a particular emp_id. I can achieve this by below query :

```
Table Structure:
Employee(emp_id,name,is_active)
Address(add_id,emp_id,address,is_active)
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE e
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS a
ON e.emp_id=a.emp_id 
WHERE e.is_active='A'
AND a.is_active='A';
```

Using above query it does not return any employee details if no active address. I want to return active employee details anyways even if it does not have any active address.

Note: as I am using Hibernate looking for a query without using ON . Only Where clause can be used here.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `a.is_active='A'` in `ON` clause not in `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE e
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS a
ON e.emp_id=a.emp_id AND a.is_active='A'
WHERE e.is_active='A';
```

Since you have restrictions on using condition in `on` clause you can try below approach. It will return rows where address is active or address is not available (assuming that is_active column is never null in address table).

```
Schema and insert statements:

 create table EMPLOYEES(emp_id int, name varchar(20), is_active varchar(10));
 create table Address(add_id int ,emp_id int ,address varchar(50),is_active varchar(10));

 insert into EMPLOYEES values (1,'NAME1','A');
 insert into Address values(1,1,'addr1','N');
 insert into Address values(2,1,'addr1','N');
```

Query:

```
 SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES e
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from Address where is_active='A') a
 ON e.emp_id=a.emp_id 
 WHERE e.is_active='A'
 AND (a.is_active='A' or a.is_active is null);
```

Output:

| EMP_ID | NAME | IS_ACTIVE | ADD_ID | EMP_ID | ADDRESS | IS_ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NAME1 | A | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=20afdd508bb2b25d0b44e69b9e085ba7)*

Comment: I can not use ON due to some hibernate constraints. Looking for a solution using where clause or anything else.

Comment: What if there one employee has 2 address and all those 2 address are inactive. In this case even if employee is active will not fetch the employee. Not sure how to fix it. Can you give any idea

Comment: @AvinashJethy I have revised my answer.

Comment: In case of emp_id 101 has multiple add_id 201,202 etc. Then it's fetching the records in 2 separate row. Is it possible to return all address of an employee in a single row .