# Filter Table And Left Join

Tags: sql, join, filter

I have one table "tasks" which contains two types of tasks (validation and import tasks). The validation task and the import task will process documents (document id is the the doc_id column).

tasks

---

id
doc_id
type

Sample of the data

```
id|type      |doc_id|
--+----------+------+
 1|others    |      |
 2|validation|     7|
 3|import    |     7|
 4|others    |      |
 5|validation|     8|
 6|import    |     8|
 7|validation|     9|
```

I would like to join tasks table with itself, the join condition will be the doc_id.
I need to display all validation tasks even the import tasks has not been created yet.
The expected result should be:

```
val_task          imp_task      doc_id
2                   3             7
5                   6             8
7                   NULL          9
```

I tried to use left join. My query is something like

```
select val.type,
       imp.type,
       val.id as val_task_id,
       imp.id as imp_task_id,
       val.doc_id as doc_id
FROM tasks val
left join tasks imp
on val.doc_id=  imp.doc_id
where (val.type='validation' and imp.type='import')
```

It does not return the validation task with id 7. The actual result is

```
val_task          imp_task      doc_id
2                   3             7
5                   6             8
```

Can anyone help me to correct this query please?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By filtering in the `where` you effectively have an *inner* join, the *type* should be part of the join criteria:

```
select val.type,
       imp.type,
       val.id as val_task_id,
       imp.id as imp_task_id,
       val.doc_id as doc_id
FROM tasks val
left join tasks imp on val.doc_id = imp.doc_id and imp.type = 'import'
where val.type = 'validation';
```