# SQL: Why can I not use comparison operators to compare two columns from two different tables using a join?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

For this leetcode question:
https://leetcode.com/problems/customers-who-never-order/

I know one correct way to solve this is:

```
SELECT c.name as Customers
FROM Customers AS c
LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
    ON c.id = o.customerid
WHERE o.customerid IS NULL;
```

I want to know why the following does not work:

```
SELECT c.name as Customers
FROM Customers AS c
LEFT JOIN Orders AS o
    ON c.id = o.customerid
WHERE c.id <> o.customerid;
```

Specifically, `WHERE c.id <> o.customerid` or even `WHERE c.id NOT IN (o.customerid)` does not work. The NOT IN works when you use a subquery in the where clause but not with a join the way this is written.

Why is that? I want to intuitively understand what's going on.

Comment: Your query looks like it's asking for records which satisfy both equal AND not equal conditions. Seems like a tall order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join doesn't return all rows from my left table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707673/left-outer-join-doesnt-return-all-rows-from-my-left-table)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that SQL defines tri-valued logic where predicates can evaluate to: true, false, or unknown.

In the second query the predicate `c.id <> o.customerid` evaluates to **unknown** when `o.customerid` is null.

Then, the `WHERE` clause selects only rows that evaluate to "true" and discards rows that evaluate to "false" and "unknown". In your case the rows you want will evaluate to unknown and, therefore, will be discarded.

The same logic applies to `c.id NOT IN (o.customerid)`. It also evaluates to **unknown** (not true, not false) when `o.customerid` is null.